# How to fix pagination for custom loops?

Tags: loop, pagination, query

I have added a custom/secondary query to a template file/custom page template; how can I make WordPress use my custom query for pagination, instead of using the main query loop's pagination?

#### Addendum

I have modified the main loop query via [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts). Why isn't pagination working, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Also, read this tutorial: https://devnote.in/wordpress-paginate_links-how-to-use-it It will be more help full.

Answer (score 246, accepted):

## The Problem

By default, in any given context, WordPress uses the main query to determine pagination. The main query object is stored in the `$wp_query` global, which is also used to output the main query loop:

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

When you [use a custom query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), you create an entirely separate query object:

```
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_query_args );
```

And that query is output via an entirely separate loop:

```
if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : 
        $custom_query->the_post();
```

But pagination template tags, including [`previous_posts_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_posts_link), [`next_posts_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link), [`posts_nav_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/posts_nav_link), and [`paginate_links()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links), base their output on the *main query object*, `$wp_query`. That main query may or may not be paginated. If the current context is a custom page template, for example, the main `$wp_query` object will consist of only a *single post* - that of the ID of the page to which the custom page template is assigned.

If the current context is an archive index of some sort, the main `$wp_query` may consist of enough posts to cause pagination, which leads to the next part of the problem:  for the main `$wp_query` object, WordPress will pass a `paged`  parameter to the query, based on the `paged` URL query variable. When the query is fetched, that `paged` parameter will be used to determine which set of paginated posts to return. If a displayed pagination link is clicked, and the next page loaded, *your custom query won't have any way to know that the pagination has changed*.

## The Solution

### Passing Correct Paged Parameter to the Custom Query

Assuming that the custom query uses an args array:

```
$custom_query_args = array(
    // Custom query parameters go here
);
```

You will need to pass the correct `paged` parameter to the array. You can do so by fetching the URL query variable used to determine the current page, via [`get_query_var()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var):

```
get_query_var( 'paged' );
```

You can then append that parameter to your custom query args array:

```
$custom_query_args['paged'] = get_query_var( 'paged' ) 
    ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) 
    : 1;
```

**Note:** If your page is a **static front page**, be sure to use `page` instead of `paged` as a static front page uses `page` and not `paged`. This is what you should have for a static front page

```
$custom_query_args['paged'] = get_query_var( 'page' ) 
    ? get_query_var( 'page' ) 
    : 1;
```

Now, when the custom query is fetched, the correct set of paginated posts will be returned.

### Using Custom Query Object for Pagination Functions

In order for pagination functions to yield the correct output - i.e. previous/next/page links relative to the custom query - WordPress needs to be forced to recognize the custom query. This requires a bit of a "hack": replacing the main `$wp_query` object with the custom query object, `$custom_query`:

#### Hack the main query object

1. Backup the main query object: `$temp_query = $wp_query`
2. Null the main query object: `$wp_query = NULL;`
3. Swap the custom query into the main query object: `$wp_query = $custom_query;`

   ```
   $temp_query = $wp_query;
   $wp_query   = NULL;
   $wp_query   = $custom_query;
   ```

This "hack" must be done *before calling any pagination functions*

#### Reset the main query object

Once pagination functions have been output, reset the main query object:

```
$wp_query = NULL;
$wp_query = $temp_query;
```

### Pagination Function Fixes

The [`previous_posts_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_posts_link) function will work normally, regardless of pagination. It merely determines the current page, and then outputs the link for `page - 1`. However, a fix is required for [`next_posts_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link) to output properly. This is because [`next_posts_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link) uses the `max_num_pages` parameter:

```
<?php next_posts_link( $label , $max_pages ); ?>
```

As with other query parameters, by default the function will use `max_num_pages` for the main `$wp_query` object. In order to force [`next_posts_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link) to account for the `$custom_query` object, you will need to pass the `max_num_pages` to the function. You can fetch this value from the `$custom_query` object: `$custom_query->max_num_pages`:

```
<?php next_posts_link( 'Older Posts' , $custom_query->max_num_pages ); ?>
```

## Putting it all together

The following is a basic construct of a custom query loop with properly functioning pagination functions:

```
// Define custom query parameters
$custom_query_args = array( /* Parameters go here */ );

// Get current page and append to custom query parameters array
$custom_query_args['paged'] = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

// Instantiate custom query
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_query_args );

// Pagination fix
$temp_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query   = NULL;
$wp_query   = $custom_query;

// Output custom query loop
if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :
        $custom_query->the_post();
        // Loop output goes here
    endwhile;
endif;
// Reset postdata
wp_reset_postdata();

// Custom query loop pagination
previous_posts_link( 'Older Posts' );
next_posts_link( 'Newer Posts', $custom_query->max_num_pages );

// Reset main query object
$wp_query = NULL;
$wp_query = $temp_query;
```

## Addendum: What About `query_posts()`?

### `query_posts()` for Secondary Loops

If you're using [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) to output a custom loop, rather then instantiating a separate object for the custom query via [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), then you're [`_doing_it_wrong()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_doing_it_wrong/), and will run into several problems (not the *least* of which will be pagination issues). The first step to resolving those issues will be to convert the improper use of [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) to a proper [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) call.

### Using `query_posts()` to Modify the Main Loop

If you merely want to modify the parameters for the *main loop query* - such as changing the posts per page, or excluding a category - you may be tempted to use [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts). But you still shouldn't. When you use [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts), you force WordPress to *replace* the main query object. (WordPress actually makes a second query, and overwrites `$wp_query`.) The problem, though, is that it does this replacement too late in the process to update the pagination.

The solution is to *filter the main query before posts are fetched*, via the `pre_get_posts` hook.

Instead of adding this to the category template file (`category.php`):

```
query_posts( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5
) );
```

Add the following to `functions.php`:

```
function wpse120407_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    // Test for category archive index
    // and ensure that the query is the main query
    // and not a secondary query (such as a nav menu
    // or recent posts widget output, etc.
    if ( is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        // Modify posts per page
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 ); 
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse120407_pre_get_posts' );
```

Instead of adding this to the blog posts index template file (`home.php`):

```
query_posts( array(
    'cat' => '-5'
) );
```

Add the following to `functions.php`:

```
function wpse120407_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    // Test for main blog posts index
    // and ensure that the query is the main query
    // and not a secondary query (such as a nav menu
    // or recent posts widget output, etc.
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        // Exclude category ID 5
        $query->set( 'category__not_in', array( 5 ) ); 
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse120407_pre_get_posts' );
```

That way, WordPress will use the already-modified `$wp_query` object when determining pagination, with no template modification required.

### When to use what function

Research [this question and answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) and [this question and answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts) to understand how and when to use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts), and [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts).

Comment: Wish pages in the codex could be so complete.

Comment: Chip, you made my day!

Comment: Chip, you always save so much time! if only google would rank you answers higher (callout for googlers) before i went crazy searching ;) thanks.

Comment: Using your example I could not get the paging to work until I used an if-else block as found mid-way (instead of the ? : conditional) down this page: http://themeforest.net/forums/thread/pagination-on-wordpress-static-page-set-to-front-page/28120, very strange. Otherwise this answer taught me a lot.

Comment: Great answer - 1 thing, I was having problems running next/previous post link function in an ajax call - it just wouldn't take - after a quick dig around I found the global `paged` was not being updated (obv something to do with admin-ajax.php environment) so I added this: 
`global $paged;
$paged = $custom_query_args['paged'];` 
and it worked :)

Comment: *...I don't use the word 'hero' lightly, but you are the greatest hero in American history.* - Lionel Hutz

Comment: I now have pagination for my custom loop, on a main page, showing child pages. Trying to access the second page, via `http:example.com/main_page/page/2` simply redirects back to `http://example.com/main_page`. Any idea why?

Comment: And remember to flush your permalink structure (resave permalink structure settings)

Comment: Does this solution still work in WordPress 4.5+? When I follow these instructions the result shows on a "newer posts" on page 1, clicking it goes to page 2, but the subquery results are still the first 10 post.

Comment: Was fighting with my pagination for such a long time, then ready this little nugget: `Note: If your page is a static front page, be sure to use page instead of paged as a static front page uses page and not paged. This is what you should have for a static front page`

Comment: absolutely perfect works like a charm. one of the few solutions to a problem i've seen explained so clearly that actually works :D

Answer (score 22):

I use this code for custom loop with pagination:

```
<?php
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
} elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { // 'page' is used instead of 'paged' on Static Front Page
    $paged = get_query_var('page');
} else {
    $paged = 1;
}

$custom_query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    //'category_name' => 'custom-cat',
    'order' => 'DESC', // 'ASC'
    'orderby' => 'date' // modified | title | name | ID | rand
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_query_args );

if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :
    while( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>

        <article <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?></small>
            <div><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
        </article>

    <?php
    endwhile;
    ?>

    <?php if ($custom_query->max_num_pages > 1) : // custom pagination  ?>
        <?php
        $orig_query = $wp_query; // fix for pagination to work
        $wp_query = $custom_query;
        ?>
        <nav class="prev-next-posts">
            <div class="prev-posts-link">
                <?php echo get_next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $custom_query->max_num_pages ); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="next-posts-link">
                <?php echo get_previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' ); ?>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <?php
        $wp_query = $orig_query; // fix for pagination to work
        ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php
    wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query 
else:
    echo '<p>'.__('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.').'</p>';
endif;
?>
```

Source:

- [WordPress custom loop with pagination](http://web-profile.net/wordpress/themes/wordpress-custom-loop/)

Answer (score 7):

Awesome as always Chip. As an addendum to this, consider the situation whereby you are using a global page template attached to a Page for some "intro text" and it's followed by a subquery that you want to be paged.

Using [paginate_links()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) as you mention above, with mostly defaults, (and assuming you have pretty permalinks turned on) your pagination links will default to `mysite.ca/page-slug/page/#` which is lovely but will throw `404` errors because WordPress doesn't know about that particular URL structure and will actually look for a child page of "page" that's a child of "page-slug".

The trick here is to insert a nifty rewrite rule that only applies to that particular "pseudo archive page" page slug that accepts the `/page/#/` structure and rewrites it to a query string that WordPress CAN understand, namely `mysite.ca/?pagename=page-slug&paged=#`. Note `pagename` and `paged` not `name` and `page` (which caused me literally HOURS of grief, motivating this answer here!).

Here's the redirect rule:

```
add_rewrite_rule( "page-slug/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$", 'index.php?pagename=page-slug&paged=$matches[1]', "top" );
```

As always, when changing rewrite rules, remember to *flush your permalinks* by visiting Settings > Permalinks in the Admin back-end.

If you have multiple pages that are going to behave this way (for example, when dealing with multiple custom post types), you might want to avoid creating a new rewrite rule for each page slug. We can write a more generic regular expression that works for any page slug you identify.

One approach is below:

```
function wpse_120407_pseudo_archive_rewrite(){
    // Add the slugs of the pages that are using a Global Template to simulate being an "archive" page
    $pseudo_archive_pages = array(
        "all-movies",
        "all-actors"
    );

    $slug_clause = implode( "|", $pseudo_archive_pages );
    add_rewrite_rule( "($slug_clause)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$", 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', "top" );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_120407_pseudo_archive_rewrite' );
```

### Disadvantages / Caveats

One disadvantage of this approach that makes me puke in my mouth a little is the hard-coding of the Page slug. If an admin ever changes the page slug of that pseudo-archive page, you're toast - the rewrite rule will no longer match and you'll get the dreaded 404.

I'm not sure I can think of a workaround for this method, but it would be nice if it were the global page template that somehow triggered the rewrite rule. Some day I may revisit this answer if no one else has cracked that particular nut.

Comment: You could hook post save, check if the page has your archive template under the meta key `_wp_page_template`, then add another rewrite and flush rules.

Answer (score 4):

> ## I have modified the main loop query via `query_posts()`. Why isn't pagination working, and how do I fix it?

Great answer Chip created needs to be modified today.
For some time we have `$wp_the_query` variable that should be equal to the `$wp_query` global just after the main query executes.

This is why this the part from the Chip's answer:

> #### Hack the main query object

is not needed anymore.
We can forget this part with creating the temporary variable.

```
// Pagination fix
$temp_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query   = NULL;
$wp_query   = $custom_query;
```

So now we can call:

```
$wp_query   = $wp_the_query;
```

or even better we can call:

```
wp_reset_query();
```

Everything other Chip outlined stays.
After that query-reset-part you can call the pagination functions that are `f($wp_query)`, — they depend on `$wp_query` global.

---

In order to further improve the pagination mechanics and to give more freedom to the `query_posts` function I created this possible improvement:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/39483

Answer (score 3):

```
global $wp_query;
        $paged = get_query_var('paged', 1);

    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => '{your_post_type_name}',
        'meta_query' => array('{add your meta query argument if need}'),  
        'orderby' => 'modified',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'paged' => $paged 
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    if($query->have_posts()):
        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
            //add your code here
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_query();

        //manage pagination based on custom Query.
        $GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages = $query->max_num_pages;
        the_posts_pagination(array(
            'mid_size' => 1,
            'prev_text' => __('Previous page', 'patelextensions'),
            'next_text' => __('Next page', 'patelextensions'),
            'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __('Page', 'patelextensions') . ' </span>',
        ));
    else:
    ?>
        <div class="container text-center"><?php echo _d('Result not found','30'); ?></div>
    <?php
        endif;
    ?>
```