# Pagination works in custom query loop but it doesn't work in shortcode

Tags: wp-query, pagination

It is possible for shortcodes?
Paggination works fine on custom template page.But I want to display the posts with shortcodes.
Posts are displayed well.But pagination  works incorrectly.The same posts on all pages.
My custom query loop in page template:

```
$page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;  
        $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' =>'1', 
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post_type' => 'accomodation',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'accomodation_category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'gostinnitsy-2'
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'location',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'litva'
        )
    )
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
// Pagination fix
$temp_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query   = NULL;
$wp_query   = $custom_query;

?>

  
 have_posts() ) :
    while ($custom_query-> have_posts() ) :
        $custom_query->the_post();?>
                






  

max_num_pages );


$wp_query = NULL;
$wp_query = $temp_query;?>
```

And my shortcode in function.php

```
function accomodation_catalog_shortcode( $atts )
{
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
     'accomodation' => '',
     'location'     => '',
     'number'       =>'-1',
     'orderby'      => 'post_date'
   ), $atts));
    $page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;  
     global $post;
        $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' =>$number, 
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post_type' => 'accomodation',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'accomodation_category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $accomodation
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'location',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $location
        )
    )
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
// Pagination fix
$temp_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query   = NULL;
$wp_query   = $custom_query;

?>

  
 have_posts() ) :
    while ($custom_query-> have_posts() ) :
        $custom_query->the_post();?>
                






  

max_num_pages );


$wp_query = NULL;
$wp_query = $temp_query;?>

    

I corrected the error:'paged' => $page,
and pagination work!

But why when I want to display shortcode content under page content, shortcode content are displayed above page content?

In admin:

<p>page content<p>
[ accomodation-catalog location='slug ' accomodation='slug']


display

<div>shortcode content</div>
<p>page content<p>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix pagination for custom loops?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops)

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm...
It looks like your shortcode function defines $page, but the query itself uses `$paged`....with a `d` on the end. Maybe remove the `d`?
In other words, try changing

```
'paged' => $paged
```

into

```
'paged' => $page
```