# How to add PHP pagination to wordpress

Tags: php, functions, pagination, urls

I'm trying to make a custom PHP pagination work with wordpress, the page in wordpress is a very custom one, not a post or a page, it's a select from DB that shows flowers, the styling is ok now, but it shows all the flowers in a city and i want to limit 10 flowers per page:

```
$per_page = 10;
$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$startAt = $per_page * ($page - 1);

$user_query_subs = new WP_User_Query( array('meta_key' => 'location', 'number' => $per_page, 'offset' => $startAt, 'meta_value'  => $flow_location, 'meta_compare' => '=', 'role' => 'admin', 'orderby' => 'rand', 'order' => 'DESC'), array('fields' => 'all_with_meta') );


$all_user_query_subs = new WP_User_Query( array('meta_key' => 'location', 'meta_value'  => $flow_location, 'meta_compare' => '=', 'role' => 'admin', 'orderby' => 'rand', 'order' => 'DESC'), array('fields' => 'all_with_meta') );

$all_flowers = $all_user_query_subs->get_total();
$flowers = $user_query_subs->get_results();
```

and after the content is loaded: i'm adding the links on the bottom like this:

```
<?php
        $totalPages = $all_flowers / $per_page;
        $links = "";
        $current_url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++) {
        $links .= ($i != $page ) 
            ? "<a href='" . "$current_url" . "page/$i/'>Page $i</a> "
            : "$page ";
}
    echo $links;
    ?>
```

The select query is working perfectly, it's loading only 10 per page, but my problem is with the `links` at the bottom:

Right now when i press the page 2 to access the next 10 flowers from the city, i get `Page Not Found` from `Wordpress` but with the correct `$current_url/page/$i`

Any ideas please?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix pagination for custom loops?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [paginate_links()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) from wordpress core API, its make more easily to paginate your custom query. And you dont need to make another query to get all users count.

```
<?php
$users_per_page = 10; // total no of author to display

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
if( (int)$paged === 1 ){
  $offset = 0;
} else {
  $offset = ($paged-1) * $users_per_page;
}
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'location',
    'number' => $users_per_page,
    'offset' => $offset,
    'meta_value'  => $flow_location,
    'meta_compare' => '=',
    'role' => 'admin',
    'orderby' => 'ID',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
$fields = array('fields' => 'all_with_meta');
$user_query_subs = new WP_User_Query( $args, $fields );
$users = $user_query_subs->get_results();
if ( !empty( $users ) ) {
    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        // code goes here
    }
}
else {
    echo 'No flowers found.';
}
?>
```

And then the pagination, remember it depends on how your structure is.
If you use permalinks, then you can use this code below:

```
<?php
$query_string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; // current query parameters
$total_users = $user_query_subs->total_users; // total number of users
$total_pages = ceil( $total_user/$users_per_page ); // total number of pages

// if on the front end, your base is the current page
$base = get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '?' . remove_query_arg('paged', $query_string) . '%_%';
$paginate_args = array(  
    'base' => $base,  
    'format' => '?paged=%#%', // define the query parameter that will be used, in this case "paged" 
    'current' => $paged,
    'total' => $total_pages, 
    'prev_text' => 'Previous',  
    'next_text' => 'Next' ,
    'end_size' => 1,
    'mid_size' => 5
);
echo paginate_links($paginate_args); 
?>
```

Comment: Hullen Thanks for your answer! the URL is converting and working, the links of pagination are showing but it still goes to the `NOT FOUND PAGE` , i rebuilt the permalinks but no success... any idea?