# Custom template pagination

Tags: templates, pagination, paginate-links

I have a custom post type "news". I created the page "News" with the id 55 and a custom template file. I want to implement pagination.

The problem is when I access the news with a page number set I get an error "404 not found". URL looks like this "/news/page/2/". I use `paginate_links` function to display pagination.

How to display the correct page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix pagination for custom loops?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've created a ***Custom Post Type***, then WordPress should be able to handle this for you automagically. Check the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

Instead of creating a "Page" and trying to paginate that, [create `archive-{post_type}.php` instead](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Post_Types_display). That file will be used as the index file for your CPT, and will show up automatically at `http://yoursite.com/news`.

You've made this too complicated, unless there is a lot of information missing from the question.