# Tag page only display 10 posts

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, loop, tags, get-template-part

I've had a problem with this for quite some time now and cannot for the life of me figure it out. I am using Multi-site and not sure if that has anything to do with it or not, so keep that in mind.

## Problem:

When clicking on tags on a post or custom post type, I only get the default post count set by WP which is 10 posts as results.  Pagination shows at the bottom for next post and older posts, but when I click on either link, page 2 is not found and it sends me to 404 page. There is a mix of regular posts and then custom posts types that should be showing, but regardless the post type, it only shows 10 even though there are hundreds.

At first I was using the Twentyten way of showings tags which was using `get_template_part()` and redirecting to a loop.php page.  I have sense eliminated that process and created my own tag.php page and use the default wordpress loop to query for posts.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

However I had to use this bit of code to query for all posts types and not just the regular ones.

```
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 'post_type' => array('post, cool_tools, tribe_events') ) );
query_posts( $args );
```

My pagination code for the page reads :

```
<div id="nav-below" class="navigation">
    <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
    <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
</div><!-- #nav-below -->
```

The url to the missing page is:

```
/tag/tagname/page/2/
```

Can anyone tell me why WP wont find any more tags?

### **Update

As per Chip's example, here is how I have it setup now.

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tag_slug__and' => $tagname,
    'paged' => $paged
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
```

Yet when I click newer posts at the bottom, it still takes me to a 404 page and no page 2 found for tags.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix pagination for custom loops?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `query_posts()`. It is stomping on the default query, and killing your pagination. Don't use `query_posts()`. Filter `$wp_query` at `pre_get_posts` instead:

```
function wpse123674_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    // Only modify the main query on the tag archive index
    if ( $query->is_main_query && $query->is_tag() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array('post, cool_tools, tribe_events') );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse123674_pre_get_posts' );
```

This belongs in `functions.php`. In your template file, simply remove all references to any query modification.

Answer (score 0):

I also advise, to click "**PERMALINKS --> SAVE**" once again, to reflush cache.