# What is wrong with this pagination code?

Tags: wp-query, pagination

I'm trying a new approach to paginate posts returned in a category.php file. I want to see snippets of 10 posts at a time. Filename is category-xyz.php and this worked before I changed to this method, although I was using showposts=200 and it was returning all 180 posts in that category.

I changed method because several calls I used were deprecated (eg showposts) or not advised. I am using this post's solution for reference:

[How to fix pagination for custom loops?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops)

Here's my code:

```
<?php
// Define custom query parameters
$custom_query_args = array( 
'cat' => 76, 
'posts_per_page' => 5
);

// Get current page and append to custom query parameters array
$custom_query_args['paged'] = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

// Instantiate custom query
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_query_args );

// Pagination fix
$temp_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query   = NULL;
$wp_query   = $custom_query;

        // Output custom query loop rather than use wp_query
        if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : 
             while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : 
              $custom_query->the_post();
        // Loop output goes here
        ?>
            <div class="pcrmbimgholder">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><img src="<?php echo pcrmbimagegrab() ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a>
            </div>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <?php the_content_limit(190, ""); ?>                
                <?php $customField = get_post_custom_values("price"); 
                 if (isset($customField[0])) { 
                 echo "<strong>Price: ".$customField[0];
                 echo "   </strong>";
                } else { 
                ;
                }
                ?>  
                <?php $customField = get_post_custom_values("sku"); 
                 if (isset($customField[0])) { 
                 echo "&#124;   Stock Reference: ".$customField[0] . "&#32;&#32;&#32;";
                } else { 
                ;
                }
                ?>      
        <a class="postbutton" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><span>View</span></a><div class="separator"></div>     


        <?php

    endwhile;
endif;
// Reset postdata
wp_reset_postdata();

// Custom query loop pagination
previous_posts_link( 'Older Posts' );
next_posts_link( 'Newer Posts', $custom_query->max_num_pages );

// Reset main query object
$wp_query = NULL;
$wp_query = $temp_query;

?>
```

I have also tried this because I am not sure which parameters I need in the custom query array:

```
// Define custom query parameters
$custom_query_args = array( 
'cat' => 76, 
'posts_per_page' => 5,
'max_num_pages' => 20,
'paged' => $paged,
);
```

The pagination link goes to /category/category-name/page/2/ which results in a 404 error. Any ideas why?

Comment: try to enable DEBUG http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress to possibly get error messages

Comment: Thanks. I did this and it said there was an unexpected colon in the code of the custom query loop. I copied and pasted again and it seemed to work. However the pagination link goes to /category/category-name/page/2/ which results in a 404 error. Will update the post.

Comment: This: `$custom_query->while ( have_posts() ) :` should be written as `while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :`. It _was_ wrong in the source Answer too.

Comment: @CharlesClarkson  Thanks Charles, good catch. I did correct this (the linked answer has 2 examples of that code, 1 is correct) and now I'm at the 404 error mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, @CharlesClarkson. Probably one of my best typos of all time. (I fixed the other one, too.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main query runs *before* the template is loaded, and WordPress decides what template to load based on the results of that query.

You say your default `posts_per_page` is set to 200, and there are 180 posts in that category, so as far as WordPress knows, *there is no page 2*. Your custom query that you run in the template with a different posts per page setting is unrelated to the main query.

The solution is to make adjustments to the main query *before* the template is loaded, via the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action. This would go in your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function category_posts_per_page( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin()
        && $query->is_category()
        && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'category_posts_per_page' );
```

You can then run the normal loop in the template and pagination will work as expected. Also see [`is_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category) in Codex if you want this to apply to a specific single category.

Comment: In the original files I was using 'showposts'. I have changed it to this <?php $recent = new WP_Query("cat=154&posts_per_page=-1"); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?>   but it still doesn't work with the new function you mentioned. Can you explain what you mean by 'normal loop' please?

Comment: normal loop meaning no custom query, get rid of all your custom query code and just run the plain `while( have_posts() )` loop.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, I still get all posts returned. Should that posts_per_page in functions.php override my posts_per_page=-1 in the category template file?

Comment: if you've removed the custom query from your template, there should be no query arguments there at all. your template should just be the default, plain, unedited category template.

Comment: That works a treat thanks, removed all query calls like you said.