# Difference between an archive and a page listing posts

Tags: posts, pages, archives

I am wondering what is the difference between a wordpress archive page, and just a page template listing out posts?

Right now I have a custom archive page, listing all entries of a custom post type. This could very well have been handled by just a normal page.

Right now I am going to list out all blog posts (not on the front page, but as a `news` option in the menu), and I am wondering if I should use an archive page or create a page template that lists out posts. What is the different in intent for these pages?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Archive Page

An *archive page* is part of the WordPress Template Hierarchy, and is the template file WordPress uses to display the *archive index list* for a given post type. The [custom post type archive template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Post_Types_display) is as follows:

- `archive-{posttype}.php`
- `archive.php`
- `index.php`

WordPress uses the query parameters to output this page, and posts are output via the *main/default query loop*.

#### Advantages

- Pagination works out of the box
- No user intervention required to create/display; WordPress creates the archive index view automatically, based on `register_post_type()` parameter `has_archive`

#### Disadvantages

- Pretty permalink might not be as *pretty* as you'd like - though you can modify it via `register_post_type()`

### Custom Page Template

A *custom page template* can be used to display any arbitrary content. When used to display a listing of custom post-type posts, it does so using a *secondary query* loop.

#### Advantages

- User control of pretty permalink, via static page permalink

#### Disadvantages

- Pagination will not work out of the box, and [must be fixed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops)
- User intervention required to create this page: create static page, assign page template

Comment: Well, then I think it is better to use the archive way, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming these are going to be *all* posts within your posts section, and not excluding any, why not create a page in WordPress called "News" and then set that to as your "Posts Page" in Settings -> Reading? (I would have left this as a comment, but it won't let me unless I have a reputation of 50).

The [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) may contain some useful information for you as well. I believe in most cases the normal content loop and archive loop are the same, with the archive template it has the variable Page title (ex: "Daily Archives:" "Category Archives:") and you can also create additional archive templates based on different data (like post type, specific category, etc).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Well, all `news`, which is of the standard post type. I have a custom post type excluded. And the page will be paginated.