# posts_nav_link(); not showing up on static pages

Tags: theme-development, wp-query, loop

I've got two different loops. The default on the homepage, but a secondary loop on the archive page. It grabs all the content, like so:

```
<?php // WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'posts_per_page'         => '3'
);
// The Query
$archiveQuery = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $archiveQuery->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $archiveQuery->have_posts() ) {
        $archiveQuery->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="post">
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
    <?php  first_item(); ?> </a>
```

However, when I include `posts_nav_link();`, it does not show up. Is this because it is a static page? I am using this for an infinite scroll.

Answer (score 2):

[`posts_nav_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/posts_nav_link) is intended for archive pages. That function uses `get_next_posts_nav_link` which [uses the `global` variable `$wp_query`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1720). There is a check for `!is_singular()`. That will always be false on your "static" page, since `$wp_query` will represent the page (single) and not the query you have created. So, yes, it is because it is a static page.

Chip Bennett wrote/compiled an fairly exhaustive answer [explaining how to make pagination work](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/120408/21376).

Comment: Would there be a simpler solution, seeing as I just need a list of all the URLS from a loop, rather than the specific permalink functions? So in theory, to call the loop again in the footer, and using `<?php the_permalink() ?>`?

Comment: Sorry? Easier than what? The hard part is keeping the query synced with the pagination. Creating the links is easy.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure and include a wp_reset_postdata() at the end of a loop created with WP_Query.

> Use `wp_reset_postdata()` to restore the global $post variable of the
>   main query loop after a secondary query...
>   https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata

```
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';

    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();

} else {
    // no posts found
}
```