# repeating posts on 2nd page to posts

Tags: loop, pagination

I am having an issue where I wanted to strip out all categories but one from the homepage so I added the following to the loop:

`query_posts('cat=2');`

However now the issue is that page one of the homepage is fine, however if you use the pagination at the bottom and select page 2 it will reproduce the exact articles on the homepage e.g.

http://alumen.s.strategiesuk.net/ - Home page 
http://alumen.s.strategiesuk.net/page/2/ - 2nd page of Home

Any help on the subject would be greatly appreciated.

(I am using the theme Gonzo)

Comment: [Do not use `query_posts`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/27722), and have a look at [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/120407/27722).

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your child themes functions.php file

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category_posts' );

function exclude_category_posts( $query ) {

if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home() ) {

$query->set( 'cat', '-27,-30' );
    }
}
```

Add a comma separated list of category i.d's to the set.

**Never Use Query Posts**