# How to add archives (with pagination) to page template?

Tags: wp-query, pagination, archives

So the site I'm building has a few different archives pages. For the newest one I'm building, I tried to copy the `archive.php` I've got:

**page-archives.php**:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<section role="main" class="main">

    <h1>Archives</h1>

    <?php get_template_part('inc/loops/default','default-loop'); ?>

    <?php custom_pagination(); ?>

</section>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**inc/loops/default.php**:

```
<?php

global $query_string;
$results = new WP_Query($query_string);

if ($results->have_posts()) :
    while ($results->have_posts()) :
        $results->the_post();
                    // DO STUFF HERE.
             endwhile;
    endif;

?>
```

And the `custom_pagination` function in **functions.php**:

```
function custom_pagination() {
    global $wp_query;
    $big = 999999999;
    echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'type' => 'list'
    ));
 }
```

Whenever I do `global $query_string` or `global $wp_query`, it thinks the query is for the Archives page (which it is) and I'm not sure how to break out of that.

I can work around that by putting the loop directly in the `page-archives.php` without `$query_string` and call `paginate_links()` instead of calling it's wrapper, *but I'd rather not do that*.

Also, I have an `archive.php` which is basically this, but I can't figure out how to get it to work for all posts. I need to answer this question anyways for a few other custom archives.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix pagination for custom loops?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops)

Comment: @ChipBennett I'll take a look. Thanks so much, I tried looking for this, but I'm unsure how to title my problem.

Comment: @ChipBennett I think with this solution I'll have to repeat code, which is what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: If your theme includes a template tag for pagination like most of the default themes, you could simply add it to your custom archive or category template.