# Properly display posts on homepage

Tags: posts, categories, homepage

I'm having trouble displaying posts from a single category on the homepage the way I want them to appear. The theme I'm using uses a 3 column layout for the homepage and a content-sidebar layout for the blog page.

Basically I want the [homepage](http://music1.netlabs.co.za/) to display exactly like the [blog page](http://music1.netlabs.co.za/?cat=7), but include the slider. So what I did was just copy the code from `category.php` and pasted it into a new custom page template titled `hompage.php` and set that as my homepage.

But for some reason its not displaying any posts and I have no idea why.

category.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Category pages.
 *
 */
$settings = get_option( "ntl_theme_settings" );
get_header(); ?>



        <div class="outer">
                <div class="frameset container clear">
                        <?php if ($settings['ntl_disable_audio'] != 'off'){     ?>
                        <div class="clear headtop">    
                                <div class="page-title" >
                                        <h1 class="vfont"><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h1>
                                </div>

                                <?php echo lets_get_albumselector(); ?>                                        
                                <?php echo lets_get_musicplayer(); ?>

                        </div>                         
                        <?php } else { ?>

                        <div class="clear headtop" style="height: auto;">                                      
                                <div class="page-title" style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 40px;">
                                        <h1 class="vfont"><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h1>
                                </div>                 
                        </div>

                        <?php } ?>

                        <?php if (!$settings['ntl_show_timer']) { ?>
                                <div class="cdowntop"> 
                                <?php echo get_for_timer(''); ?>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                                <div class="cdownnone">
                        <?php } ?>

<div class="bodymid hfeed hpage">
        <?php if ($settings['ntl_disable_audio'] != 'off'){     ?>
                <div class="drawer">&nbsp;</div>
        <?php } ?>
        <div id="main">
                <div id="content" role="main">
                        <div class="container clear">
                                <div class="grid8 first">              
                                        <div id="content" role="main">
                                                <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'category' ); ?>                              
                                                <?php adminace_paging(); ?>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
<?php lets_make_carousel(); ?>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

loop.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The loop that displays posts.
 *
 */

?>

<?php /* If there are no posts to display */ ?>
<?php if ( ! have_posts() ) : ?>
        <div id="post-0" class="post error404 not-found">
                <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Not Found', 'localize' ); ?></h1>
                <div class="entry-content">
                        <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found for the requested archive. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'localize' ); ?></p>
                        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
        </div><!-- #post-0 -->
<?php endif; ?>

<?php
        /* Start the Loop.
         *
         *
         * Without further ado, the loop:
         */ ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


                <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

                        <?php if ( !is_search() ) { ?>
                        <h3 class="entry-title excpts vfont" style="margin: 0px;"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                        <div class="vmeta smallfont">
                                <?php ntl_posted_on(); ?><a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )); ?>"><?php echo get_the_author(); ?></a>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        $pphoto = '';
                        $pphoto = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'imlink');
                        if ($pphoto) {
                        ?>

                        <div class="excpt">
                                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

                        </div>
                        <div class="menu-content" style="width: 286px; position: relative;">
                        <div class="mencontent">
                                <div class="imgblock" ><div class="imlk imgoverlink6 menimg">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail('imlink'); ?>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span class="imgblockover imgoverlink6">&nbsp;</span></a>
                                </div></div>
                                <div class="ctime clear smallfont">
                        <?php the_time('j') ?>
                        <?php the_time('M') ?>
                                </div> 
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                        <?php } ?>

                        <?php } else { ?>
                        <div class="foodmenu searchresult">
                        <h2 class="entry-title vfont excpts"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
                        <span class="clear"></span>
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>

                </div>

                <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: A question should not _rely_ on external pages. Please include minimal code examples in your questions.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but if you've set a certain page to display as the home page in Settings > Reading, then you need to save your template as `front-page.php` not `homepage.php`.  `homepage.php` is used when the home page just displays the most recent posts.

Comment: Actually, `homepage.php` is not a valid template file name, and won't be used at all, unless as a properly configured custom page template.

Comment: The page you have linked as the "blog page" is *not*, in fact, the *blog page*, where "blog page" means *blog posts index*. The page you've linked as the "blog page" is actually the **archive index page for category ID 7**.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're making this far more difficult on yourself than you need to.

### Easiest Solution

First, I'm a bit confused, because the page you call the "blog page" is not actually the blog page. The blog page is the *blog posts index* page, and the page you've linked is actually the **category archive index for category ID 7**.

If you really want this:

> Basically I want the homepage to display exactly like the blog page, but include the slider.

And you want to call the Category 7 Archive Index page the "Blog" page, then the solution is really quite simple:

1. Go to `Settings -> Reading`
2. Change "Front page displays" from "a static page" to "latest posts"

Then, you can do one of two things:

1. Add the slider to `header.php`, using as `if ( is_front_page() )` conditional wrapper
2. Create a `home.php` template file (the template file used to display the blog posts index), and add your slider there.

### Convoluted Solution

If you really want a custom static front page and a separate blog page, first ensure that you have the static front page configured properly:

1. Create a static page, named (arbitrarily) "Front Page" or "Home Page" or whatever you want
2. Create a static page, named (arbitrarily) "Blog" or whatever you want
3. Go to `Settings -> Reading`
4. Change "Front page displays" from "latest posts" to "a static page"
5. Select the page created in Step 1 as the "Front page"
6. Select the page created in Step 2 as the "Posts page"

Then, you just need to configure your template files.

In this case, you can let the blog posts index fallback to `index.php`, and you'll be good to go there. But for the front page, you'll need to create `front-page.php`, with the following:

1. The slider code where appropriate
2. A custom/secondary query, using `new WP_Query()`.
3. [Pagination fix](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops).

This solution is much more complicated. I would recommend going with the easier solution.

Comment: I tried both solutions without any luck. Let me try to clarify what's happening using images.