# Paginate_links links not working accordingly to how I do query the page

Tags: custom-post-types, paginate-links

Ok, I've a custom post type page to which I have attached the `paginate_links` function to navigate through the elements.

If I don't do anything and let WP using whatever mechanism is attached to the archive page, then the `paginate_links` work fine but the previous link never goes back to the page one.

Changing manually the links works fine.

On the contrary, if I do something like the answer suggested [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops), overriding the `wp_query` object, the `paginate_links` move to the second page but the "current" remains set always on page 1.

**CODE**

```
$current = get_query_var('page') ? get_query_var('page') : 1; // Get query var
$record_per_page = 2; // How many faqs to display on each page
$offset = ( $current - 1 ) * $record_per_page;

    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'faqs',
        'orderby'           => 'date',
        'order'             => 'desc',
        'page'              => $current,
        'offset'            => $offset,
        'posts_per_page'    => $record_per_page,
    ); 

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $temp_query = $wp_query;
    $wp_query = NULL;
    $wp_query = $the_query;

    $row                = 1;
    $total              = ceil(wp_count_posts('faqs')->publish / $record_per_page);

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        echo get_the_ID();  
    endwhile;

    // Reset postdata
    wp_reset_postdata();

    if ( $total > 1) {

        $paginate_links = paginate_links( array(
            //'base'      => @add_query_arg( 'page', '%#%' ),
            'base'      => '%_%',
            'prev_text' => __('« Indietro'),
            'next_text' => __('Avanti »'),
            'mid_size'  => 5,
            'format'    => '?page=%#%',
            'current'   => $current,
            'total'     => $total
        )); echo $paginate_links;
    }

// Reset main query object
$wp_query = NULL;
$wp_query = $temp_query;
```

Any idea of what's happening?

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Code updated above. Please bear in mind that if I use the "paged" variable I always get a 404 error page. I don't know whether this could be the solution, but I wasn't able to figure out the reason of my 404.

Answer (score 1):

[`paginate_links()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) has what I consider a horrible bug in that it does not work correctly in many cases with the default `base` argument, or even with the more complicated sample `base` in the Codex-- `'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),`. The first link won't get the pagination argument appended, the link defaults to "this page", and that means that you can't get back to the first page.

The solution I've found for getting around that issue is to use an absolute URL in the `base`-- something like `'base'      => get_permalink().'%_%',`

Comment: But that's not what it happens to me ... or at least the argument is there, but it's the wrong one. I will give this solution a go and let you know.

Comment: That is what you describe-- "the paginate_links move to the second page but the "current" remains set always on page 1"

Comment: No, that's not what I have described ... the "current" get set to 2 ... but the internal link to go back to page 1 show page=2.

Comment: That sounds like exactly the same thing to me, but no point arguing. If this answer doesn't help, then hopefully someone else will happen by with an answer that does.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the issue seems to be connected with the base and format parameters. I may not able to explain properly technically what has happened. 
However, from what I see in my archive page, my page parameter is by default "page" and not "paged" as expected.

That said, when using the base parameter set to '%#%' the hash is supposed to take the correct previous or next page number. This make impossible to use the format and tweak the output if required.

On the contrary, using the '%_%' that force WP to use the format parameter setting the '%#%' as part of the value gets WP to always use the current page everywhere.

So the solution I found was to tweak everything in the base parameter like in the following snippet:

```
$paginate_links = paginate_links( array(
                'base' => preg_replace('/\?.*/', '/', get_pagenum_link()) . '%_%',
                'prev_text' => __('« Indietro'),
                'next_text' => __('Avanti »'),
                'mid_size'  => 5,
                'current'   => $current,
                'total'     => $totalpages
            ));
```