# How can I paginate this?

Tags: loop, pagination, query

Been trying to use the pagination functions in wordpress with this code

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
$args = array( 'post_status' => 'pending', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'paged'=>$paged);
$recent_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php while ( $recent_posts->have_posts()) {
$recent_posts->the_post();
echo '<div id="votes"><li id="voteimage"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . esc_attr( $recent["post_title"] ) . '">';
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"], 'thumbnail');
echo '</li></a>';
echo '<li class="vote-title"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' . get_the_title() .'</a> </li>';
echo '<li class="vote-desc"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_excerpt(10) . '</a> </li>';
echo '<ul class="vote-footer"><li>Author: <a href="http://streakingpirates.com/forum/users/' . get_the_author() . '">' . get_the_author() . '</a></li></ul>';
echo '</div>'; 
} 
?>
<?php posts_nav_link(); ?>
<?php next_posts_link('« Previous Entries') ?>
<?php previous_posts_link('Next Entries »') ?>
```

And yet each time I try I just can't seem to get it right, any help would be appreciated cheers.

Result page here: http://streakingpirates.com/pending/ *excuse the random posts by my friend*

Solution found thanks to cale_b and the link he provided https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/120408/11704

needed to swap

```
<?php next_posts_link('« Previous Entries') ?>
```

for

```
<?php next_posts_link( 'Older Posts' , $custom_query->max_num_pages ); ?>
```

since apparently the previous pages link has some issues with custom loops

Comment: Where is the pagination function you are trying to use? Or, are you meaning that it's not listing the right number of posts? (It is).  What do you mean, `can't seem to get it right?`

Comment: I'll add things such as "posts_nav_link();" and it doesnt show, think I need to use the $recent_posts in there somewhere, not sure

Comment: Got it.  OK, the issue is that it's a custom loop - in order to do pagination on a custom loop, there's a lot of special things you need to do.  See this answer (very thorough) which should get you where you need to be: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/120408/11704

Comment: That's a long read! Cheers I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

needed to swap

```
<?php next_posts_link('« Previous Entries') ?>
```

for

```
<?php next_posts_link( '« Previous Entries' , $custom_query->max_num_pages ); ?>
```

since apparently the previous pages link has some issues with custom loops

Solution found thanks to cale_b and the link he provided https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/120408/11704

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see three posts! :-)

Just an idea, but maybe you only need to add the next/prev links? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/posts_nav_link

Edit:

This (http://streakingpirates.com/pending/page/2) works for me, so I guess it must be the links you're after!

Comment: That's mostly my problem, I do that and nothing appears, not sure if I'm placing it correctly or I'm missing a $recent_posts to fix it. I've put it in the edit to show you the new code but it's appearance on the website doesnt change at all

Comment: I don't see any posts_nav_link() or previous_posts_link() in your code. Are you calling those functions at all?

Comment: Just added it to show you, sorry took a while to edit.

Comment: Where's your "endwhile" ? :-) Your call needs to be outside the loop I believe. - Oh sorry totally misread that... let me give it a look

Comment: Where do I put the endwhile?

Comment: My bad, it's well-placed (the brackets), I misread your code.

Comment: It shows on the page2 you linked me to as it says "Next Entries" at the bottom, but not on the first

Comment: Did you refresh permalinks? I honestly can't think of anything else. Looks fine. Maybe you could do a var_dump on your query to see what's happening?

Comment: Well, next entries makes sense, but on the first it should show "previous entries"

Comment: fairly new to PHP so where would I place the var_dump? I assume it shows error messages or the process? and wouldnt know how to refresh permalinks.

Comment: Just visit the permalinks page in Wordpress admin and apply it again. I don't think it's gonna be the problem, but it sometimes solves a lot of otherwise weird behaviour. As for var_dump you can just var_dump($recent_posts); to see what your query returns. But if you're fairly new to php I wouldn't mess too much with it. Most likely it's a syntax error or something, since at least the "next posts" link works on the other page.

Comment: No ending ";" on your last two functions. Or is that a typo?

Comment: Found the issue but cheers! I'll post the solution

Comment: Answers should be [more than plain links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). They should actually be an answer instead of a route where someone will _maybe find_ an answer. Please help preventing link rot, [edit] your answer and provide the needed information that helps the OP as well as later visitors to solve their problem. Also please avoid extended discussion in comments - there's [chat] for that.