# Unable to display paging navigation with a custom post type loop

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, pagination

I have used a starter pack for my WordPress theme development, but I can't display the navigation on a custom post type loop.

The framework starter is : http://underscores.me/

There is my PHP Code into my template file to loop into the files

```
<?php
            wp_reset_postdata();

              $args = array(
                  'post_type' => 'testimonial',
                  'order' => 'ASC',
                  'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                  'posts_per_page' => 2,
                  'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1
                  );

              // The Query
            $wp_testimonials = new WP_Query();
            $wp_testimonials->query($args);

              // The Loop
              while ( $wp_testimonials->have_posts() ) : $wp_testimonials->the_post(); 
                ?>
                    <div  id="page-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('list-sub-page'); ?>>
                        <div class="wrapper">

                            <h3 class="uppercase"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

                            <div class="the_resume">
                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                            </div>

                            <?php
                            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) 
                            {
                            the_post_thumbnail('testimonial');
                        }
                        ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <?php

              endwhile;

                ?>

                <div class="navigation">
                <?php
                miller_paging_nav();
                ?>
            </div>

                <?php


              // Reset Query
              wp_reset_postdata();

            ?>
```

And you can see for the function miller_paging_nav(); is generated by the framework and the function looks like this.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'miller_paging_nav' ) ) :
/**
 * Display navigation to next/previous set of posts when applicable.
 */
function miller_paging_nav() {
    // Don't print empty markup if there's only one page.
    if ( $GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages < 2 ) {
        return;
    }
    ?>
    <nav class="navigation paging-navigation" role="navigation">
        <h1 class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Posts navigation', 'miller' ); ?></h1>
        <div class="nav-links">

            <?php if ( get_next_posts_link() ) : ?>
            <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts', 'miller' ) ); ?></div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( get_previous_posts_link() ) : ?>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'miller' ) ); ?></div>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- .nav-links -->
    </nav><!-- .navigation -->
    <?php
}
endif;
```

I have about 6 or 7 testimonials in my custom post type but the pagination just never shows. Any one could help me?

--

**EDIT** 
I used the documentation of an other post on this website and the pagination shows but I think I might have a rewrite rule problem.

My page : http://vincent.okidoomedia.com/miller/patient/testimonials/

The documentation : [Pagination custom query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/154360/pagination-custom-query#answer-154364)

If you try to click on the #2 or #3 on my page, it always return to the main page. If I change the permalink to default, it will works. Any ideas?

Comment: Please, search this site. There a lot of questions like yours already solved. Just to point you in the direction: in your pagination function you are using the global $wp_query, not the query of your loop.

Comment: Read [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545)

Comment: @cybmeta : Yes I am currently searching arround at the same time. 

A main fact is that when I enter /page/2/ it automaticly returns me to the page 1 withtout the /page/. 

Still investigating.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is on the Bad Ideas list. While you *can* replace the query in template that tends to break things, especially pagination.

In simplified form let's say you have 10 testimonials and your WP settings are 5 posts per page:

- your template thinks there are 10 / 2 = 5 pages worth of testimonials
- but WordPress thinks there are only 10 / 5 = 2 pages!

So when URL instructs WP to show page 3... WP thinks there is nothing there. And this is just the one of *obvious* ways in which it breaks.

For any modificaiton of main loops you need to be using filter like [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) and do it before template is even reached.

Comment: Mainly, you are telling me to use the default WordPress setting of post per page and then I delete the line in my $args?

Comment: @PatricePoliquin I am telling you that the way you are doing this query now is inherently flawed and I strongly suggest to work through linked `pre_get_posts` documentation.