# Custom post type page navigation

Tags: navigation, custom-post-type-archives

I have made a custom post type archive page, but can't make the wordpress pagination work. So far the code I have is the following, but clicking on page navigation just tells me that the page cannot be found. The Custom Post Type is made with Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

```
<?php
$custom_query_args = (array(
   'post_type' => 'kampaania'
));

$custom_query_args['paged'] = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_query_args );

$temp_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query   = NULL;
$wp_query   = $custom_query;

?>
<main id="content" class="site-main">

    <?php if ( apply_filters( 'hello_elementor_page_title', true ) ) : ?>
        <header class="page-header">
            <?php
         
            the_archive_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
            the_archive_description( '<p class="archive-description">', '</p>' );
            ?>
        </header>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="page-content">
        <?php
        while ($custom_query->have_posts() ) {
            $custom_query->the_post();

            $post_link = get_permalink();
            ?>
            <article class="post">
                <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <?php
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $post_link ), get_the_post_thumbnail( $post, 'large' ) );
                } ?>
            
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
               <?php 
                $field = get_field_object('kampaania_periood'); 
                $field2 = get_field_object('kampaanias_kauplused');
                ?>
                <div class="bpost-title">
                    <?php
                    printf( '<h2 class="%s"><a href="%s">Kampaania nimi: %s</a></h2>', 'entry-title', esc_url( $post_link ), wp_kses_post( get_the_title() ) );
                    ?>
               </div>
         
               <p class="kamp-period">
               <span class="kamp-period-head"><?php echo $field['label']; ?></span> <?php echo $field['value']; ?>
               </p>

               <p class="post-excerpt">
                  <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
               </p>
         
               <p class="kamp-kaup"> 
               <span class="kamp-period-head"><?php echo $field2['label']; ?></span> <?php echo $field2['value']; ?>
               </p>

               <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn-closer">Osale kampaanias</a>
                </div>
                
            </article>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>

    <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>

    <?php
    global $wp_query;
    if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) :
        ?>
        <nav class="pagination">
            <?php /* Translators: HTML arrow */ ?>
            <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( sprintf( __( '%s Vanemad kampaaniad', 'hello-elementor-child' ), '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span>' ) ); ?></div>
            <?php /* Translators: HTML arrow */ ?>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( sprintf( __( 'Uuemad kampaaniad %s', 'hello-elementor-child' ), '<span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>' ) ); ?></div>
        </nav>
    <?php endif; ?>

</main>
```

I have made the template using Hello Elementor child theme and their archive template.

Any ideas, on how to get the pagination working?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the most relevant solution to your problem.
You just check it out:

1. **[Possible solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/154360/pagination-custom-query)**
2. **[Possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41738362/how-to-include-pagination-in-a-wordpress-custom-post-type-query)**

Comment: Unfortunately I have already worked them through, I get the pagination and everything, but still it tells me, that "It looks like nothing was found at this location." I would need someone, to tell me, what is wrong with my current code..