# Pagination re-direct to main page

Tags: pagination

This is a general question regarding pagination.

I have posts on the main page, but the pagination is redirected to main page.

For example, site.com/page/2 goes to site.com.

Is there a general setting in the backened which I can fix the redirect?

(otherwise, I am guessing it is from plugin setting).

Thanks

Comment: Paste the code from your main page in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the static front page is not supposed to be paginated.

Can you fix it? Yes you can!

Take a look at those resources for a start:

- [Codex: Pagination - static front page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#static_front_page)
- [How to fix pagination for custom loops?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/120408/22534)

Much more information about this topic is available, if you [search](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=) for it. Good luck!