# Wordpress Rewrite Issue

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, url-rewriting

I created a custom taxonomy, two actually (one tag and one category), for a page that lists a series of community projects.  This is the parent URL:

```
website.com/community
```

If you go here you'll see ALL the projects. I've successfully set up query vars so that if you enter say:

```
website.com/community/?stencil-tag=easter
```

or

```
website.com/community/?stencil-type=build
```

everything works as it should.  It's perfect.  Now, naturally, I'm trying to set up pretty permalinks so that users would simply be able to enter

```
website.com/community/tag/easter
```

and

```
website.com/commumity/type/build
```

respectively.  I feel as if the issue may have something to do with the fact that I'm trying to rewrite on a child page of the root (/community)

Anyhow, this is my rewrite function.  I've tried a bunch of deviations but I can't see to hit the mark here.  I'm remembering to flush as well.

```
add_action('init','add_community_rewrite_rules');
function add_community_rewrite_rules()
{
add_rewrite_rule(
    'tag/(\d*)$',
    'index.php?pagename=community&stencil-tag=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);

add_rewrite_rule(
    'type/(\d*)$',
    'index.php?pagename=community&stencil-type=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
}
```

If anyone sees the error of my ways here and can point me in the right direction I'd be incredible appreciative.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rewrite rules are wrong. For example, you want to rewrite from `community/tag/easter` to `'index.php?pagename=community&stencil-tag=easter'`, so the regex should contain `community/tag/` and not only `tag/`. Also, `\d` match only digits but the tag value is a string. Same apply to the rewrite for stencil-tag. You could use `.` to match any character, both numeric and strings.

```
add_action('init','add_community_rewrite_rules');
function add_community_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
       '^community/tag/(.*)$',
       'index.php?pagename=community&stencil-tag=$matches[1]',
       'top'
    );

    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^community/type/(.*)$',
        'index.php?pagename=community&stencil-type=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

Although those rewrite rules can be correct, I think you should use another approach. Use the default archive page generated by WordPress for the `projects` post type. If you need a specific template for it, create the file `archive-projects.php` in your theme folder. You can rewrite the slug from `projects` to `community` when registering the post type, if you want that URL for the post type archive:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {

    $args = array(
      //Your args here
      'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'community' ),
    );
    register_post_type( 'projects', $args );

} );
```

Then, when registering the taxonomies, you can build the rewrite rules also:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {

    //Custom post type
    $args = array(
      //Your args here
      'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'community' ),
    );
    register_post_type( 'projects', $args );

    //Custom taxonomies: stencil-tag
   $args = array(
      //Your args here
      'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'community/tag' ),
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'stencil-tag', 'projects', $args );

    //Custom taxonomies: stencil-tag
    $args = array(
      //Your args here
      'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'community/type' ),
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'stencil-type', 'projects', $args );

} );
```

Now the rewrite rules are handled by WordPres automatically and you don't need to render a page and make a secondary query for the posts inside the page as they are fetched in the main query.

Comment: Thank you.  Sincerely.  My regex game is weak, I didn't even notice but your mods worked perfectly.  I also appreciate the recommendation on proper approach.  I'll probably end up going that direction but good knowledge all around.

Comment: The only issue now is that (and this is probably one of many reasons I should use the archive template) it breaks pagination.  If I click to page 2, the URL is website.com/community/tag/easter/page/2/ and it returns an empty set even though there are more results to be shown.

Comment: The broken pagination is a common issue when using custom queries. There are several threads about that in this site. For example [this one](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops). Some times, rewrite rules for pagination may also be needed for custom queries, but not sure if this is your situation. I would need your pagination function to know it.