# Pagination in relation to archive.php

Tags: functions, pagination, archives, child-theme

A small problem here, I just don't know how to change this because I'm a self taught newbie. I made a child-theme from the [simone-theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/simone/) with a static front-page. To it I have the `archive.php` as the place for posts. Only thing is that the pagination-links to the next page aren't working properly and it only send me to the `content-none.php`. I "know" this comes from the code below having the index.php and not the `archive.php` as a root but how do I change this?

Here the snippet from the **template-tags.php**

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'simone_paging_nav' ) ) :
function simone_paging_nav() {
// Don't print empty markup if there's only one page.
if ( $GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages < 2 ) {
    return;
}

$paged        = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? intval( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
$pagenum_link = html_entity_decode( get_pagenum_link() );
$query_args   = array();
$url_parts    = explode( '?', $pagenum_link );

if ( isset( $url_parts[1] ) ) {
    wp_parse_str( $url_parts[1], $query_args );
}

$pagenum_link = remove_query_arg( array_keys( $query_args ), $pagenum_link );
$pagenum_link = trailingslashit( $pagenum_link ) . '%_%';

$format  = $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->using_index_permalinks() && ! strpos( $pagenum_link, 'index.php' ) ? 'index.php/' : '';
$format .= $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->using_permalinks() ? user_trailingslashit( 'page/%#%', 'paged' ) : '?paged=%#%';

// Set up paginated links.
$links = paginate_links( array(
    'base'     => $pagenum_link,
    'format'   => $format,
    'total'    => $GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages,
    'current'  => $paged,
    'mid_size' => 2,
    'add_args' => array_map( 'urlencode', $query_args ),
    'prev_text' => __( '&larr; Previous', 'simone' ),
    'next_text' => __( 'Next &rarr;', 'simone' ),
            'type'      => 'list',
) );

if ( $links ) :

?>
<nav class="navigation paging-navigation" role="navigation">
    <h1 class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Posts navigation', 'simone' ); ?></h1>
        <?php echo $links; ?>
</nav><!-- .navigation -->
<?php
endif;
}
endif;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: To see what I mean here the [site](http://schutzhuelle-frauentreff.de/archiv/). I would like to have a working pagination by changing the posted code to paginate all posts with `'category_name' => 'archive'` and not the main query. I sat on it for a while but I understand too little to be able to change the code properly.

Comment: Your static front page should be named `front-page.php`. Check [this article](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page) in the codex for more info. Also, your pagination is for the main query. You need to modify it to work with your custom query

Comment: It is! The front-page.php as it is is fine -no problem there. I have more of a problem with the query as you said. Could you link me to tutorial or sth. that would explain me how you to change the query for my needs? thank you very much!

Comment: Check [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545)

Comment: @PieterGoosen this gave my an overview over the custom query -thank you for that- but I think it didn't answer my question completely. would you kindely see for the edit I posted above?

Comment: I think [this solution](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/120408/31545) would be your best option

Comment: @PieterGoosen thank you very much! I will try it out tomorrow after work :-)