# Next Post links not working in custom post type shortcode

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode, pagination

I'm trying to paginate some custom posts types, and the previous link works, but not the next link. I tried several ways but I'm not able to find the correct one... if anyone could help :)

This is my code :

```
function livredor_function($atts,$content=''){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        id => ''
    ), $atts));


    ob_start();


    function create_guestbook() {   

        $i = 1;     

        $max_entries_per_page = 0;
        $current_page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 0;
        $gbquery = new WP_query("post_type=inliguestbook&showposts=10&paged=" . $current_page);


        while($gbquery->have_posts()) { $gbquery->the_post();
        ?>
            <div class="guestbook">
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?> <span><?php the_time('j F Y') ?></span></h3>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php
            $i++;
        }   

    ?>
    <div class="pagenav">
         <div class="pagnext"><?php next_posts_link('—›', $max_entries_per_page) ?></div>
        <div class="pagprev"><?php previous_posts_link('‹—', $max_entries_per_page) ?></div>    
    </div>
    <?php
    }   

    $gbquery = null; $gbquery = $temp;

    wp_reset_query();


    return create_guestbook() . ob_get_clean();

}

add_shortcode('livredor','livredor_function');
```

Comment: There are *two* sets of functions, firstly `previous_posts_link()`&`next_posts_link()` - plural - and secondly `previous_post_link()`&`next_post_link()` - singular. You are mixing them. Intentionally? Or is this the source of your problem?

Comment: Dear, thanks for that, this was a mistake. However, it didn't fix the problem.

But i tried several things and discover this:

if i do [code]query_posts("post_type=inliguestbook&showposts=10&paged=" . $current_page);
  while(have_posts()) { the_post();[/code] 


instead of [code]$gbquery = new WP_query("post_type=inliguestbook&showposts=10&paged=" . $current_page);  
  while($gbquery->have_posts()) { $gbquery->the_post();[/code]

I get my next link, but i get also 10 other posts after...

Comment: Instead of `$max_entries_per_page` do `$gbquery->max_num_pages` for you `next_posts_link()` call. For the `previous_posts_link()` call it is generally not needed.

Answer (score 0):

OK, thank you to ialocin, the $gbquery->max_num_pages solve it!

So there is the clean code :

```
function livredor_function($atts,$content=''){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        id => ''
    ), $atts));


    ob_start();


    function create_guestbook() {   


        $current_page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 0;
        $gbquery = new WP_query("post_type=inliguestbook&showposts=10&paged=" . $current_page);     
        while($gbquery->have_posts()) { $gbquery->the_post();

        ?>
            <div class="guestbook">
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?> <span><?php the_time('j F Y') ?></span></h3>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php
        }   

    ?>
    <div class="pagenav">
         <div class="pagnext"><?php next_posts_link('—›', $gbquery->max_num_pages) ?></div>
        <div class="pagprev"><?php previous_posts_link('‹—', $gbquery->max_num_pages) ?></div>  
    </div>
    <?php
    }   


    wp_reset_query();


    return create_guestbook() . ob_get_clean();

}

add_shortcode('livredor','livredor_function');
```

Comment: Glad to be of help. See »[How to fix pagination for custom loops?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/120407/22534)« for some optimization you can and probably should do.

Comment: Don't do `$gbquery->max_num_pages = 0;` it is useless and wrong, as the variable will be set by your `WP_Query` call. Besides where you do it, there it isn't there yet anyway. If you had debugging turned on, then you would have gotten some messages about it.