# Overriding $wp_query on a template

Tags: wp-query

What would be the **disadvantages/problems** of overriding a global variable, in this case the $wp_query?

Example in template **archive-books.php**:

```
get_header();
global $wp_query;

$wp_query = new WP_Query( 'post_per_page=6&post_type=books' );
```

Comment: Why would you want to? On the books archive page that should already be the query, basically. Maybe you are needing to change the post limits?

Comment: I'm having pagination problems. The pagination functions gets its query info from the main query and so I would like to know the disadvantages of overriding it vs sending a custom query object to the pagination function.

Comment: See the link in my answer.

Comment: One more thing, maybe just for the future, but generally custom loops are seldom needed, especially for archives.

Comment: You might find [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545) helpful

Comment: I have found an issue with doing date meta_query with archives, where the posts don't have the date stored in the right format, and for brevity it hopefully is easier to override the query for that case rather than add an additional custom field onto the posts, but I'm trying both ways...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are interfering with the main query/loop, which is **bad** - there is nothing more to say.

You can do a *custom* loop, see the codex article [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) to start with, or use the [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) hook, if you want to do something other then the usual behaviour.

If you need to toy with `$wp_query`, for example to [fix the pagination on custom loops](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/120408/22534), then restore it afterwards.