# Pagination for custom loop on custom page template is not displaying anything

Tags: wp-query, loop, page-template, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I have created a page where user can see his favourite post which has been bookmarked by him

```
get_user_favorites($user_id);
```

This function is responsible for returning me all the favourite posts bookmarked by user in an array.

I am using this approach to get the data from the database and make it work inside my Custom Html.

```
    <?php $user_fav = get_user_favorites($user_id); 
      $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
       $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => 4,
        'post_type'        => array('communityposts','post','video'),
        'post__in'         => $user_fav,
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters' => true ,
        'paged'            => $paged
      );
      $posts_array = get_posts( $args );
       foreach ($posts_array as $p) :

    ?>

<article class="post-items-latest">
  <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $p->ID ); ?>" title="<?php echo $p->post_title; ?>">
    <span class="image-wrapper">

      <?php
        $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id($p->ID);
        $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); //get full URL to image (use "large" or "medium" if the images too big)
       ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $img_url; ?>" alt="<?php $p->post_title; ?>" width="226" height="117">

    </span>
    <h1><?php echo $p->post_title; ?></h1>
  </a>
  <div class="post-footer">
    <span class="user"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo get_the_author_link(); ?></span>
    <span class="data"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>&nbsp;<?php wp_days_ago_v3(); ?></span>
    <span class="likes"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo $meta_values = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'cv_post_views_count', true ); ?> </span>
  </div>
</article>

<?php endforeach; ?>


<div class="post-nav-container">
  <?php previous_posts_link( __('&rarr; Older Posts','circoviral')); ?>
  <?php next_posts_link( __('&larr; Older Posts','circoviral')); ?>
</div>
```

Using this approach i am able to get the Favourited post by an User but i am not able to make the `next_posts_link();` and `previous_posts_link();` work inside my template

Is there anything i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Don't use get_posts(), rather use WP_Query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach was also correct but the only problem was we were missing is that resetting the query before the post navigation links.

Here is the updated answer.

```
  <?php $user_fav = get_user_favorites($user_id); 
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
     $args = array(
      'posts_per_page'   => 4,
      'post_type'        => array('communityposts','post','video'),
      'post__in'         => $user_fav,
      'post_status'      => 'publish',
      'suppress_filters' => true,
      'paged'            => $paged,
      'order_by'         => 'date',
      'order'            => 'ASC' 
    );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $wp_query->have_posts()):while($wp_query->have_posts()):$wp_query->the_post();

  ?>

  <article class="post-items-latest">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
      <span class="image-wrapper">

        <?php
            $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
            $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); //get full URL to image (use "large" or "medium" if the images too big)
            $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 226, 117,true,true,true); //resize & crop the image
          ?>

          <?php if(!empty($image)): ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" width="226" height="117">
          <?php else: ?>

            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()): ?>

          <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'large'); ?>

            <?php endif; ?>
          <?php endif; ?>

      </span>
      <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </a>
    <div class="post-footer">
      <span class="user"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo get_the_author_link(); ?></span>
      <span class="data"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>&nbsp;<?php wp_days_ago_v3(); ?></span>
      <span class="likes"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo $meta_values = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'cv_post_views_count', true ); ?> </span>
    </div>
  </article>

  <?php 
    endwhile;
    endif;
  ?>

  <div class="post-nav-container">
    <?php previous_posts_link( __('&rarr; Older Posts')); ?>
    <?php next_posts_link( __('Newer Posts &larr; ')); ?>
  </div>
  <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: @terminator changed the complete code , so i just posted his previous code that helped me to solve the problem , Only Problem was resetting the query before the navigation  links. I didn't tested his new answer so i am not sure it will gonna work or not !

Answer (score 1):

Harman, don't use `get_posts()` when `pagination is required`. You may also accomplish this task using `WP_Query`.

Refer to this answer explained beautifully by Chip Bennett at

[How to fix pagination for custom loops?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops)

```
    <?php $user_fav = get_user_favorites($user_id); 
      $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
       $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => 4,
        'post_type'        => array('communityposts','post','video'),
        'post__in'         => $user_fav,
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters' => true ,
        'paged'            => $paged
      );
      $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
      $temp_query = $wp_query;
      $wp_query   = NULL;
      $wp_query   = $loop;
      if( $loop->have_posts()):while($loop->have_posts()):$loop->the_post(); 
    ?>

<article class="post-items-latest">
  <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
    <span class="image-wrapper">

      <?php
        $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
        $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); //get full URL to image (use "large" or "medium" if the images too big)
       ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $img_url; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" width="226" height="117">

    </span>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
  </a>
  <div class="post-footer">
    <span class="user"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo get_the_author_link(); ?></span>
    <span class="data"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>&nbsp;<?php wp_days_ago_v3(); ?></span>
    <span class="likes"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo $meta_values = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'cv_post_views_count', true ); ?> </span>
  </div>
</article>

<?php 
endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>

<div class="post-nav-container">
  <?php previous_posts_link( __('&rarr; Older Posts')); ?>
  <?php next_posts_link( __('Newer Posts &larr; ',$loop->max_num_pages)); ?>
</div>

<?php 
$wp_query = NULL;
$wp_query = $temp_query;
?>
```

Comment: No luck ,still Not getting the pagination links

Comment: Ur navigation links not showing up or they are not working

Comment: Links are not showing up

Comment: @HarmanPreet Please try the updated anwser, it may work

Comment: It is working now ! I just made some changes in your previous code . I will post the answer soon . Thanks for the help

Comment: @HarmanPreet as this answer solved your issue, you should, in good sportmanship and in appreciation, accept this answer by clicking on the checkmark next to this answer. Thank you :-)

Comment: I have just posted the updated answer , Thanks for your help @terminator