# WP_Query for liked posts is showing all posts if none are liked

Tags: wp-query, ajax, masonry

I'm using the plugin [Favorites for WordPress](https://favoriteposts.com/) to allow visitor's to like products presented with a Masonry grid on the site. On the site I have a page which lets the visitor see all his or hers liked products and it loads them 20 per page with AJAX.

I used [This guide](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops) for my WP_Query and everything works fine as long as the visitor has liked posts, but if there are no liked posts - the page is showing *all* posts from the site instead of triggering the else-statement for $custom_query->have_posts();

Any suggestions? The code:

```
<? get_header(); ?>
<?
$likedposts = get_user_favorites($user_id = null, $site_id = null, $filters = null);

// Define custom query parameters
$custom_query_args = array( 
    'orderby' => 'DATE',
    'post__in' => $likedposts,
    'posts_per_page' => 20
);

// Get current page and append to custom query parameters array
$custom_query_args['paged'] = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

// Instantiate custom query
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_query_args );

// Pagination fix
$temp_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query   = NULL;
$wp_query   = $custom_query;

if ($custom_query->have_posts()) :?>
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main loop-content" role="main">
            <ul class="grid grid-all" id="grid-index">
                <? while ($custom_query->have_posts()) : 
                    $custom_query->the_post();
                    $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail_size' );
                    $url = $thumb['0']; ?>

                    <li class="product-item">
                        <div class="pi-heart">
                            <? echo do_shortcode('[favorite_button post_id="" site_id=""]'); ?>
                        </div>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" data-fancybox-type="ajax" class="various fancybox.ajax lighten" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" data-class="<?php echo get_post_type( get_the_ID() ); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></a>
                    </li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul>
        </main><!-- #main -->
        </div><!-- #primary -->
<? else: ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<? endif;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<div id="nextnav" style="display: none; background-color: white; border: 3px solid black; z-index: 99; text-align: center; width: 200px;">
    <? 
        next_posts_link($custom_query->max_num_pages);
        // Reset main query object
        $wp_query = NULL;
        $wp_query = $temp_query;
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: rather than check if the query has posts, check if `$likedposts` is empty and don't run the query.

Comment: Ah of course! I wrapped the query with

 if (!empty($likedposts)){ }

and now it works as intended. Thanks!