# Pagination not working on static page

Tags: wp-query, pagination, media

I am using the following code to display media files on a custom static page. Files display properly but pagination is **not** working. How can I solve this issue?

Following code shows the media files:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'posts_per_page' => '10',
    'paged'          => $paged,
    /* 'numberposts' => -1, */
    'post_status'    => null,
    'author'         => $current_user->ID,
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    /* 'caller_get_posts' => 1, */
);
// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

$attachments = get_posts( $args );
if ( $attachments ) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        echo '<tr><td><a href="' . wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID ) .
            '" rel="shadowbox" title="' . $attachment->post_excerpt . '">';
        echo ($attachment->_wp_attached_file);
        echo '</a>
        </td>';
        </tr>';
    }
}
```

Added following to `functions.php`:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'my_pagination' ) ) :
    function my_pagination() {
        global $wp_query;       
        $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer        
        echo paginate_links( array(
            'base'         => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
            'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
            'total'        => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
            'prev_next'    => True,
            'prev_text'    => __( '« Previous' ),
            'next_text'    => __( 'Next »' ),
            'type'         => 'plain',
            'add_args'     => False,
            'add_fragment' => '',
            'before_page_number' => '',
            'after_page_number'  => ''
        ) );
    }
endif;
```

Page number or pagination not working, calling the function in my static page like so:

```
echo my_pagination( $args );
```

Answer (score 1):

Dear I have wasted my week on this problem, basically when you select static page as your home page in setting->reading of wordpress the complete behavior of listing things are changed, basically static pages are never meant for pagination the fact is when you call the $paged variable it will always return zero even if you define its value to 1 the pagination will just refresh your page, because its a page not a .php valid file page is already a taxonomy function that is called in index.php of main wordpress the function will always return same thing no matter what you do,

The work around make a index.php file copy all the content from that static page to it and then replace it with your index.php and select latest post in setting->reading of wordpress

Now if you really don't want to mess with it, but still want to have the pagination then you need to write a small code of yours for pagination

basically home.com/page/2 will never work but home.com/?page=2 will always work but changing the permalink structure will change it for every thing so we will create a pagination function that will call next page with home.com/?page=2 structure url

```
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* PAGINATION */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------*/

//paste this where the pagination must appear

global $wp_query;
$total = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
// only bother with the rest if we have more than 1 page!
if ( $total > 1 )  {
     // get the current page
     if ( !$current_page = get_query_var('paged') )
          $current_page = 1;
     // structure of "format" depends on whether we're using pretty permalinks
     if( get_option('permalink_structure') ) {
         $format = '?paged=%#%';
     }
     echo paginate_links(array(
          'base'     => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
          'format'   => $format,
          'current'  => $current_page,
          'total'    => $total,
          'mid_size' => 4,
          'type'     => 'list'
     ));
}
```

if you include this code where this rather than the current pagination you will see it working :)

Answer (score 0):

Pagination is always based on main query that is in your case is static page and has only one page hence no pagination.

You need to do a simple hack as provided in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/120408)

Answer (score 0):

// Its working on home page 
set the "paged" parameter (use 'page' if the query is on a static front page)

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : '1';
$args = array (
    'nopaging'               => false,
    'paged'                  => $paged,
    'posts_per_page'         => '1',
    'post_type'              => 'post',
    'category__not_in' => array(97),
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
print_r($query);
$total_pages = $query->max_num_pages;


if ($total_pages > 1){

    $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
    echo '<div class="navigation">';

    echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => $current_page,
        'total' => $total_pages,
        'type'      => 'list',
        'prev_text'          => __('Previous Posts'),
        'next_text'          => __('More Posts'),
    ));
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite older but still my answer will be helpful, I hope, as I was in this condition for last 2/3 days and solved it now. The simple fact is

> Static front pages uses get_query_var( 'page' ) and not get_query_var(
>   'paged' ).