# yet another: custom post type with pagination not working in Wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

Firstly; I have searched high and low for a solution to the problem I am having (over the last 2-3 weeks), but nothing I have done has been able to get the pagination working for a post displaying a grid of posts. I would include more links in this post (including website in question) but I am limited to posting 2 urls.

(The theme being used is Divi, by Elegant Themes. ..child theme is being used)

**So:**
I have created a CPT and am using Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) to enable a simple admin page for the user to enter details (for each new post). This creates the new post of the CPT.

Posts that are created with this CPT are automatically listed on a 'Travel Blog' page in grid format. (..removed site URL..)

When a post from the Travel Blog page is selected for viewing, it displays an introductory page [post] that displays a grid of all blog posts with the category that is relevant for that page (trip) - not the CPT. It is this page where I would like the pagination, and these are the pages where the problem is.

The code for creating the CPT and for displaying the grid of posts is the following:
http://pastebin.com/mM3XPUHM

This page (amongst many many others I have read) would appear the best resource I can find, but maybe there is something I haven't understood?
[How to fix pagination for custom loops?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops)

**Maybe some useful info**
- the page displaying the post grid to be paginated is a Post as opposed to a page (with reference to WP terminology)

- the grid of posts being displayed (where pagination is not working) are not of the CPT. They are displayed as per the relevant category - an ACF variable
- when mouse pointer hovers over 'Older Posts' link, url is shown with '/page/2/' added, but when clicked, the first initial page is shown
- if tested, the variable of 'max_num_pages' will return a number greater than 1, so there are numerous pages to display
- I am not able to manually enter the URL with /page/2/ added, in the address bar. Initial page is displayed.
- if I enter a fixed category for the post grid (as opposed to the ACF variable) it makes no difference, except for displaying a grid of posts of the same category on each page
- if I enter a number for 'paged' in code. eg. '$args['paged'] = 3' the third page will actually be displayed

-- with the previously mentioned test, the link for 'Newer Posts' is still not displayed. Only 'Older Posts' is displayed.

I realise this is probably a reasonably long post and maybe there are still important details I have not mentioned, but here's hoping that someone might have some suggestions.

Thanks

**Progress Edit:**

While reading the [WP codex for pagination](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination) it suggested setting permalinks to default, so I set to plain (I did have 'Post Name' selected) and the pagination actually works. I would much prefer using 'Post name' for permalinks, but hopefully this should help with fault finding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has finally been resolved for me. In short, the solution is posted here:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/url-rewriting-on-custom-post-type/#post-7720726

...and this is the eventual code that was added to the functions.php file in the child theme:

```
function fix_request_redirect( $request ) {
    if ( isset( $request->query_vars['post_type'] )
         && 'custom_type' === $request->query_vars['post_type']
         && true === $request->is_singular
         && - 1 == $request->current_post
         && true === $request->is_paged
    ) {
            add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', '__return_false' );
    }

    return $request;
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'fix_request_redirect' );
```

...'custom_type' is to be replace by the actual title of the Custom Post Type.

Thank you for your effort at helping @bynicolas

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are confusing the query with your pagination logic.  You are saying if `get_query_var('paged')` is `false` get `get_query_var('page')` but you are **NOT** on a static front page and then else kicks in and sets `$args['paged'] = 1` so essentially always giving you the first set of posts in the loop.

I would try writing the query this way instead.

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; // If we have a 'paged' parameter, set $paged to that value, if not set it to 1

$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'posts_per_page' => 6,
   'paged' => $paged, // Our current paged parameter set above.
   'order' => 'desc',
   'orderby' => 'date',
   'tax_query' => array(
       array(
           'taxonomy' => 'category',
           'field'    => 'slug',
           'terms'    => get_field('category_to_display'), // category from the Advanced Custom Field variable
       ),
   ),
);


$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

also, I noticed you are setting next post to older post

```
next_posts_link( '&laquo; Older Posts' );
```

and previous post to newer post

```
previous_posts_link( 'Newer Posts &raquo;' );
```

wouldn't you want that the other way around? But then it might just be me who's not thinking straight on that one!

Comment: Thank you for having a look. Your suggestion is what I had originally (which didn't, and still doesn't make any difference sadly - I did just try). The code I posted here was an effort to try something else. ...the reason for 'next' and 'previous' links being the way they are, is because only one of them is displayed (previous_posts_link doesn't get displayed). I figured that, as list is 'desc', the next posts to display are older posts. Again, just an attempt at trying various options. Unfortunately for me, I have gotten myself in a little over my head, but am determined to work this out.

Comment: Ok, a few more question are coming up in my mind. Where is the custom query code residing (in archive-major_trip.php, in functions.php ...)? Also, are you using the default WP htaccess rules or do you have some customization/more rules there?  The query looks good like it is, so the issue is coming from elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure there is something I have done, or have overlooked. I have made 'single-major_trip.php' which is in the child directory. The standard 'single.php' file for the theme was used as a base, but I am starting to wonder if that's where the problem lies? (it still has some references that are specific to the Divi theme, although I have removed many already). I am looking now at creating a new single.php file with only what is required as bare minimum for WP. As for htaccess, I have made no changes - only plugins such as WordFence maybe?

Comment: ...have been reading about wp_link_pages(). Would this need to be included at all?  I haven't seen it referenced before in other articles/information for pagination.

Comment: Well maybe that's your problem.  single.php (or single-CPT.php) are for, well single post page.  You are working with an archive of posts for the grid and with a single when you click on one post.  I would like to see your single-major_trip.php if you could pastebin it.  As for wp_link_pages, you don't need that for what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: There's a good read for WP template hierarchy, take a look at the graphic on that page for a visual representation of that hierarchy: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Comment: I see what you mean. Could it be as simple as me putting this code in a 'archive-CPT.php' file ?   I have added the code to pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/PLfvTH0q

Comment: The code will definitely work, but I'm thinking about your link structure. 'archive-CPT.php' will automatically load when an archive request is made. you currently use this link to get to your page **/4wdaus-major_trips/turnabout-2016/** I assume _turnabout-2016_ is your CPT post.  Like I said, you could use that code in **archive-major_trips.php** but I think your grid would be accessible at **/major_trips/** or what ever slug you chose for that CPT. I'm not sure if that is the structure you want.

Comment: You should put lines 45-46 before line 28 in your code, if not you'll get a warning because $paged won't be defined at line 33. and rewrite line 45 to **$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;**  If you leave it like that, just remove line 33 to get rid of the warning

Comment: Alternatively, you could create a page template with your pastebin code. Then create a new page and assign that template to that page.  This way you could have a bit more control over the permalink structure by setting your desired page slug for the permalink. To create a new template, just add **Template Name: Major Trips Archives** as a comment at the top of your file and it will be available in the template select box when you go create a new page. Here's the documentation for more info.  https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/

Comment: Thanks for those comments.  ...first one - this could actually be where I'm messing up (and getting confused)?. The CPT is actually 'major_trips'. The 'turnabout' is a standard category. The 'Travel Blog' page is the one that shows the grid of CPT (not requiring pagination). When one of the CPT items is clicked, it then displays a grid of the category that was selected to be presented. ....there is some 'nesting' of categories going on. I do a 'rewrite' when creating the CPT, for slug to be '4wdaus-major_trips' (mostly as an attempt to get it working)

Comment: ...your second comment - I have followed the instructions outlined in original post "How to fix pagination for custom loops".  But have tried alternatives and nothing makes any difference. Will probably look at trying this code in an 'archives...' file

Comment: ...your third comment - yes, someone else has suggested this also. Maybe this is the way to go?  I have some research to do. :/

Comment: Ok, I think I understand better your situation.  I propose you to continue this conversation over chat. If you wish, we can discuss more how WP hierarchy is working so you better understand how to setup your pages and code.  here's the link for the chat room (you should have access regardless of your reputation, but this is my first chat, so if it's not working let me know) https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43693/wpse-233885

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use chat as I don't have the required reputation. It certainly would have been easier, I agree. In response to your last question there - no, the pagination is not working :/  ..with rewrite: I did that because there were issues with a page url/permalink having same name as CPT. I did this to see if there was conflict there. No go. ... the rewrite changes slug from 'major_trip' to '4wdaus-major_trips'. ...I think having categories as part of URL is fine, but at this stage, I'll do what ever is needed to get pagination working.

Comment: fyi: I am working on a test site at: 4wdaus.com/4wdtest .....Thank you for your offer of answering other questions. Is there maybe another place we can do that? ...other chat area/forum?

Comment: This is strange, I am supposed to be able to give you access to the chat room even if you don't have enough rep. It says that I can only add people that have visited chat.stackexchange.com.  try to do that maybe it'll work

Comment: Hmm, ok. I'll try again. I did try replying where I could, but I wasn't able to do anything. Will be on the comp again in about 45-60 mins

Comment: Very strange, there seem to be another user on chat with your handle, and it doesn't seem to be related to you (no wordpress.stackexchange.com profile) anyways, I'll be out for the night let me know if you got any invitation from chat.  Also let me know if you have a user profile on chat. Maybe I'm sending the invite to the wrong user?

Comment: Ok. I'm about to log on, so will have a look

Comment: I just saw you leave the chat room, but I can't post message anywhere. There's nothing I can do really.

Comment: Then maybe if we log at the same time, I can see you too and then give you permission. I see the link to grant permission, but it doesn't look like it's working!

Comment: That sounds like an idea. I really appreciate your persistence. Thank you. ...I do have something to report though. I was reading through WP codex for pagination and it suggested changing permalinks to 'plain' to see if it makes any difference ....and it did!!  It actually works. So the issue is somehow related to the 'pretty' permalinks. I don't know if that might help you?  As far as time zone goes though, I am in Australia (Brisbane, Queensland), so we might need to coordinate a time for a chat.

Comment: `get_queried_object_id()`

Comment: That was really helpful Nathan {not} ... I will look it up and see what I can find

Comment: ok, I tried again to add a user to chat! The docs says I can add people with not enough privileges but when I try to do it, it fails ! Go figure! anyhow, I'm still willing to help if you still have the issue, I'm not sure but we could chat on IRC (freenode)? I can setup a chat room. As for synchronizing time, I'm in Canada Eastern TimeZone so it looks like we have 15 hours difference.