# How to add pagination to custom page

Tags: pagination

I am using the loop in my custom page template as you can see in my code. Only 2 posts must be shown and for the rest I should be able to have pagination.

```
<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    query_posts( 
        array (
            'posts_per_page' => 2,
            'post_type' => 'post', 
            'category_name' => 'news', 
            'category' => 1,
            'paged' => $paged )
    );      
    // The Loop
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
        <div class="news-page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="news-page-content">
                <h1><a class="read-more"href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h1>
                <figure><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></figure>
                <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt();?></p>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More&raquo</a>
            </div>
         </div>  
    <?endwhile; 
    // Reset Query
    wp_reset_query();
  ?>
  <?php next_posts_link(); ?>
  <?php previous_posts_link(); ?>
```

How can I have pagination using the loop with category ID?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below URl to find your solution

[How to fix pagination for custom loops?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops)

Comment: Links are not helpful as answers.

Comment: Please edit your answer with the appropriate details. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tax_query filter: like this

```
    $args = array
    (
        'post_type' => 'item',
        'nopaging' => true,
        'tax_query' => array
        (
           'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
           'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
           'terms' => $term_id
        ),
        'meta_query'  => array(
           'key'     => 'from_import',  
           'value'   => '1'
        )
    );
    $posts = query_posts( $args );
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?