# Posts loop with pagination on a single post page

Tags: wp-query, loop, pagination

Today, I need your help.

On my pages I have a sidebar with :

```
        <div class="sidebarActu">
            <ul>
            <?php
            $i = 1;
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
                <li <?php if($i == 1){?>class="selected"<?php } ?> > <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content1', get_post_format() );?> </li> <?php
            $i++;
            endwhile; ?>
            <li class="all"><?php echo previous_posts_link();?> | <?php echo next_posts_link(); ?></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

This works perfectly !

Now, on my `single.php`, this not works because `have_posts()` returns 1 ...

So I tried something :

```
        <div class="sidebarActu">
            <ul>
            <?php
            $i = 0;
            $posts = get_posts();
            foreach($posts as $post){
                $pid = $post->ID;
                $date = $post->post_date;
                $date = date_create($date);
                $date = date_format($date, 'd/m/y');
                ?>

                <li <?php if($id == $pid){?>class="selected"<?php } ?> ><h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php get_site_url(); echo $post->post_name; ?>"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></a></h2><span><?php echo $date; ?></span></li>
                <?php
                if (++$i == 4) break;
            }
            ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Works perfectly, but can't have pagination. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is, [`get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) does not work with pagination. In stead you should use [`wp_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters), like this:

```
$args = array ('posts_per_page' => 5);
$posts = new WP_Query ($args);
```

Comment: Beware that normal pagination functions like `previous_posts_link` will only work on the primary loop on a page. This is a secondary loop. Read this post on how to paginate a secondary loop: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops

Comment: and read https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Adding_the_.22paged.22_parameter_to_a_query