# Show pagination in WP_Query

Tags: pagination

I'm coding a foodblog and I'm trying to show favorite posts list in a specific page but I have some issue with pagination. I've tried different solutions searching in previous questions but nothing solve the problem. Thanks a lot

```
 <?php $my_favs = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'user_favs', true);

         $args = array(
                'post_type' => array('recipe', 'post'),
                'post__in'  => $my_favs,
                'post_author' => get_current_user_id(),
                'pagination'             => true,
                'posts_per_page'         => -1
            );

            $recipes = new WP_Query( $args );
 while ( $recipes->have_posts() ) : $recipes->the_post(); ?>

                        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                            <h2>
                              <?php $title = get_the_title();
                                echo wp_trim_words($title, 4);?> 
                            </h2>
                        </a>
                        <p>
                            <?php $content = get_the_content();
                             echo wp_trim_words($content, 9, "...");?> 
                        </p>

          <?php endwhile; // End of the loop.?>
            <div class="pagination">
                <?php 
                    echo paginate_links();
                ?>
            </div>


            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix pagination for custom loops?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops)

Answer (score 0):

This is the pagination function I use. 
I'm not sure if the github link is the original credit, but its one i found.
Add the following to your functions.php file:

```
/**
 * Creates Custom Pagination
 * @link https://gist.github.com/rgfx/755cfb71fd1732e4e7b7bdcbd4b6e4e3
 * @param  string $numpages  [description]
 * @param  string $pagerange [description]
 * @param  string $paged     [description]
 * @return html
 */
function custom_pagination($numpages = '', $pagerange = '', $paged='') {


if (empty($pagerange)) {
    $pagerange = 2;
}

/**
 * This first part of our function is a fallback
 * for custom pagination inside a regular loop that
 * uses the global $paged and global $wp_query variables.
 * 
 * It's good because we can now override default pagination
 * in our theme, and use this function in default quries
 * and custom queries.
 */
global $paged;
if (empty($paged)) {
    $paged = 1;
}
if ($numpages == '') {
    global $wp_query;
    $numpages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    if(!$numpages) {
            $numpages = 1;
    }
}

/** 
 * We construct the pagination arguments to enter into our paginate_links
 * function. 
 */
$pagination_args = array(
    'base'            => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
    'format'          => 'page/%#%',
    'total'           => $numpages,
    'current'         => $paged,
    'show_all'        => False,
    'end_size'        => 1,
    'mid_size'        => $pagerange,
    'prev_next'       => True,
    'prev_text'       => __(''),
    'next_text'       => __(''),
    'type'            => 'plain',
    'add_args'        => false,
    'add_fragment'    => ''
);

$paginate_links = paginate_links($pagination_args);

if ($paginate_links) {
    echo "<nav class='custom-pagination'>";
        echo "<span class='page-numbers page-num'>Page " . $paged . " of " . $numpages . "</span> ";
        echo $paginate_links;
    echo "</nav>";
}
```

}'

Then, inside your archive template, add this right before your [wp_reset_postdata();](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) :

```
<!-- pagination here -->
<?php if (function_exists(custom_pagination)) {
    custom_pagination($post_query->max_num_pages,"",$paged);
} ?>
```

Also, it may depend on what page template you are on. Im assuming a custom template or an archive page template.

Next, if youre still having trouble, then id suggest checking your $paged variable, like so:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$suri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    // check $paged variable
    echo '<pre style="display:none; text-align: left; overflow:visible!important; z-index: 10000; position: relative;">';
    print_r($paged);
    echo '</pre>';
// grab the last number from the url to use as the $paged variable
$exp_suri = explode('/',$suri);
$page_query = $exp_suri[2];
$page_num = substr($page_query, -1);
$paged = is_numeric($page_num) ? $page_num : $paged;
    // Now, check $paged variable again
    echo '<pre style="display:none; text-align: left; overflow:visible!important; z-index: 10000; position: relative;">';
    print_r($paged);
    echo '</pre>';
```

You can probably remove or comment out the second part ($exp_suri to the end) to begin.
The pre tags here are **display:none**, so either take that out of the inline style, or show it using dev tools.

Finally, if youre still stuck, id read the [WordPress pagination trouble shooting, here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination).