# Woocommerce pagination and result count after custom loop

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic

Im trying to get proper display of pagination and result count after running my custom query.

Right now results of query are displayed properly but seems to me that result count and pagination is displayed for all product in shop.

After digging into problem i found out that i created separated query object instead of replacing main query. I tried to fix this following the guide here : [How to fix pagination for custom loops?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops)

.. but this is a wordpress way and i need to transform this :

```
global $loop ;

  $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' =>$per_page,
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                'key' => '_product_brand',
                'value' => $val,              
                    )

            )     
      );  


    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

         // pagination fix
    $temp_query = $wp_query;
    $wp_query = NULL;
    $wp_query = $loop;
    
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );  
        endwhile;
    } else {
        echo __( 'No products found' );
    }
    
    wp_reset_postdata();
    
    $wp_query = NULL;
    $wp_query = $temp_query;
```

..into woocommerce function.
So far i've tried changing global variable **$loop** for **$woocommerce_loop** but it's producing errors.

I also tried to pass $paged attribute like :

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

 $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' =>$per_page,
            'paged' => $paged,
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                'key' => '_product_brand',
                'value' => $val,              
                    )

            )     
      );
```

and also like :

```
$args['paged'] = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
```

Both of methods failed, they properly displaying products but not pagination neither result count.

What's the issue here?
I would really appreciate for any help, thank you.

**#EDIT 1**
After following CFX guide : https://cfxdesign.com/create-a-custom-woocommerce-product-loop-the-right-way/

Pagination and result count started to finally work. My issue here was using WP_Query instead of wc_get_products.

Following the woocommerce documentation for wc_get_products function : https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query

i achieved proper display of products with my custom key. But not all of the arguments from documentation are working for me. For instance i can't display products from category nor products with given price.

```
 $all_products   = wc_get_products(array(
                'category'             => array( 'suspension' ),
                'price'     => 59.99,
                'regular_price' => 59,
                'sale_price'    =>159,               
            ));
```

I tried to pass those arguments one by one, everything according to documentation so it should work but it isn't.
It's producing this error :

> Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array in E:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\data-stores\class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php on line 1673
>
> Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in E:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\data-stores\class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php on line 1673

**#EDIT2**

arguments :

```
$all_products   = wc_get_products(array(
                'product_category'  => 'suspension',
            ));
```

handler :

```
if ( ! empty( $query_vars['product_category']) ) {
        $query['tax_query'][] = array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
            'terms'         => esc_attr( $query_vars['product_category'] ),
        );
        return $query;
    }
```

I want to display products from parent category with given slug. This code is working only if i pass category id.
If i pass slug as argument (like in code above) loop is displaying all products in the shop.

Comment: Sorry, but your code makes no sense at all... There is no point in this part: `$wp_query = NULL; $wp_query = $loop;`. Why assign a NULL if you want to assign another value right after that. And why assign anything to `wp_query` if right after that you use `$loop` to loop your posts...

Comment: I did those things following the guide. In my understanding zero'ing the main query has to eliminate potentional errors during overriding. Then the purpouse of the assigning my $loop into wp_query is for making pagination works. My loop is outputing posts but it doesn't impact original query which is resposible for pagination and result count. I saw this kind of code working in guide (link provided in question above), but my case in slightly different than that because im using woocommerce instead plain wordpress.

Comment: it makes no sense at all. If you assign value to variable, then you just assign it - there's no point in doing it twice. And if you don't modify global $wp_query then there's no point in storing it some temp variables and so on. Change the tutorial, because this one is really bad - author doesn't understand basics of PHP nor WP. PS. WooCommerce and other third-party plugins are off-topic on this site.

Comment: What object? You create this loop on your own in your code...

Comment: Simplyfying my statement : $woocommerce_loop is fetching it results from somewhere. I thought that it's from wp_query (like in wordpress) but it seems to me that it's taking its results from other object and im trying to figure out this exact object.

Comment: Yes i did. I forget to change line with global variables so it wasn't clear that im using 2 global objects here :  $loop and $wp_query...  I would love to change the guide but there isn't any woocommerce exaples that i could use. Anyway woocommerce has some object that is resposible for fetching $woocommerce_loop values ( i suppouse its woocommerce main loop). In wordpress that object was 'wp_query' but in woocommerce similar values are assigned to different $key. I just want to found out that key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're complicating things quite a bit with some of your query syntax, and WooCommerce actually discourages using `WP_Query()` to retrieve products. They even claim it can end up breaking down the road.

I recently wrote an article on how to do what you want, complete with an example here: https://cfxdesign.com/create-a-custom-woocommerce-product-loop-the-right-way/

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what i was looking for. Thank you! Now i have to transform all WP_Queries into wc_get_products. So i have a question for you: did you used complex queries in your project? I mean the ones with specified meta_key, meta_value, price range between given values etc.. ?

Comment: I haven't attempted that but it may work. Give it a shot and I'll do my best to help if you run into a problem.

Comment: I updated the post. Can you look into #EDIT1 and tell me if those arguments are working for you?

Comment: They're not working, but if I format them like you would format a [`WP_Query()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) then the taxonomy query works just fine. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the price values, but you may need a custom `meta_query` key to accomplish what you want. Check the [`WC_Product_Query()` class](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.4.0/includes/class-wc-product-query.php#L28) for valid arguments.

Comment: That's strange, core arguments aren't working. Seems like i need to inform woocommerce support. Yes i solved pricing with `meta_query`. FYI I'm using pricing with my custom filters - user is passing 'price_min' and 'price_max' and then im displaying products between given price range. Now im just wondering how to solve category problem. For categories with given id i used tax_query, but what with categories with given slug? For them `category` argument is broken..

Comment: `category` is strictly for the WordPress native `category` taxonomy. If you mean to filter by `product_cat` then you'll need a `tax_query` which I confirmed works as expected. You may want to post your completed solution as an update.

Comment: `tax_query` works as expected but still i can pass only parent category id, and i need to pass parent category slug as argument. I'll for sure make an update for future readers.

Comment: Can you please update with the current code you have and details about what you expect to happen and details about what's happening instead?

Comment: Ofcourse, take a look at #EDIT2.

Comment: It's unclear what you're attempting to do here. Please include the full code. If this is a page template, please include it. I have no idea why you split this up into "arguments" and "handler" or what those are supposed to mean.

Comment: Since `category` argument is broken i'm trying to find other way to display all products from given category. So i want to pass category slug as argument.

Comment: I found how to display products from category using parent category id and i achieved this using `tax_query`. Now im wondering if it's possible to setup `tax_query` so i can pass category` slug` instead of category id. || `product_category` isn't build in argument so woocommerce treating it like a custom, and custom arguments have to be handled manually, exactly like a custom meta_keys (check documentation)

Comment: ...but what about `result count`? it seems that it doesn't shows proper count of products we've got using @cfx approach. As far as I understood `$total` (`woocommerce_result_count()`) is taken from `wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' )`, and I see that we changed it to `$products->total` and only then made `do_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop');`

But $total in  `Showing x - x of x results` is not reacting on this...

Comment: @Able it works just fine. If you paste a Gist to your entire template's code then I'll try to see why it may not be working for you.