# Prev / Next Post Same taxonomy Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, terms

I have a custom post type "cases" and a custom taxonomy "before-after-gallery".
On my single-case.php my prev and next post links are jumping from one category to another.

```
    <?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next Case', TRUE , null , 'before-after-gallery');?>
```

I am telling WP to stay in the same term and not sure why its jumping. I have spent hours trying multiple solutions but no matter what I can not get the post to stay in the same category.

This only happens on the cases in which have multiple terms on each case. 
I have tried to omit the other terms but I can not find a way to say "this is my current term" and get the id of that term and omit others.

Running a standard wp loop

Comment: This answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30171620/107244

Comment: $GLOBALS['just_this_category'] = 2; this cant work, due to the fact if i were to go to the next post the cat id would change , I dumped out the vars for the next post and the top post was the non correct category id.

Comment: What do you consider the 'current term' for a single post? is it the first-listed term? something else? if it's first-listed, you could use something like wp_get_post_terms()[0] to retrieve the first result and use that as the current term, and exclude all others in the array.

Comment: That is correct except its not the 1st in the array, its the second, so I go from catNameOne click next.. then the term[0] is not catNameOne its catNameThree, so I would not be able to tell which catNameXXX I am in once I leave the current Cat.
I must be missing something, i am single- .php and the prev and next are in the loop.

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything - this is expected behavior based on how the in_same_term parameter is described on https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link.  You'd probably need to write a custom wp_query filtering posts by a specific term, then add post-navigation to that. This answer goes into a ton of detail that might help: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/120408/16