# White screen of death on index.php page 3 and above?

Tags: theme-development, loop, pagination, navigation

I am experimenting with custom loops and following the tutorial of the illustrious [Chip Bennett](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops/120408#120408), and I actually got everything to work on index.php!

...

Up to, that is, page 3.

Everything works lovely when I go to page 2. On any higher page, it's white screen of death time.

To my eye, my code is practically identical to the one provided in the link, but for completeness:

```
    $hero_args = array(
    "posts_per_page" => "1",
    );

$hero_args['paged'] = get_query_var( 'paged' ) 
    ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) 
    : 1;

$heroPost = new WP_Query($hero_args);

<div class = "blog_content_wrap">
           <div class = "hero_blog">
               <?php    $temp_query = $wp_query;
               $wp_query   = NULL;
               $wp_query   = $heroPost;?>

               <?php if ($heroPost -> have_posts()): ?>
                Query contains something
              
                <?php while ($heroPost -> have_posts()):
                    $heroPost -> the_post();
                    the_title();?>
                   
                    
                <?php endwhile;
       
               ?>
                

               <?php else:?>
                No posts found, sucker
               <?php endif; 

               wp_reset_postdata();
               
            
               print_r ($hero_args['paged']);
               previous_posts_link( 'Older Posts' );
                next_posts_link( 'Newer Posts', $heroPost->max_num_pages );
               the_posts_pagination();
               $wp_query = NULL;
               $wp_query = $temp_query;
               ?>
    
           
            </div>
```

I have a sneaking suspicion it has to do with the max_num_pages? But I'm not sure at all. It's a PHP error, but I have no idea how to ask the question more precisely. If someone has a good idea of where to look, I'd appreciate it.

TLDR localhost/blogname/ = fine
localhost/blogname/page/2 = fine
localhost/blogname/page/3 = total destruction

[image: Working Fine]
[image: Total failure]

Probably not necessary, but here's my full index.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>


<!--replace index.php with the list, home.php for the 'main' blog? -->
<?php



$hero_args = array(
    "posts_per_page" => "1",
  /*  'meta_key' => 'meta-checkbox',
    'meta_value' => 'yes' */


);

$hero_args['paged'] = get_query_var( 'paged' ) 
    ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) 
    : 1;


$post_args = array(
    "posts_per_page" => "3",
    "offset" => "1",
    
);


$pag_args1 = array(
    'format'  => '?page1=%#%',
    'current' => $page1,
    'total'   => $query1->max_num_pages,
    'add_args' => array( 'page2' => $page2 )
);


$heroPost = new WP_Query($hero_args);


// the loop
?>

<?php

/*
if ( $heroPost->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $heroPost->have_posts() ) {
        $heroPost->the_post();
        if ( (int) $heroPost->current_post === 0 ) {
          // loop content for hero post
        }
    } 
}*/

?>


<div class = "blog_content_wrap">
           <div class = "hero_blog">
               <?php    $temp_query = $wp_query;
               $wp_query   = NULL;
               $wp_query   = $heroPost;?>

               <?php if ($heroPost -> have_posts()): ?>
                Query contains something
              
                <?php while ($heroPost -> have_posts()):
                    $heroPost -> the_post();
                    the_title();?>
                   
                    
                <?php endwhile;
       
               ?>
                

               <?php else:?>
                No posts found, sucker
               <?php endif; 

               wp_reset_postdata();
               
            
               print_r ($hero_args['paged']);
               previous_posts_link( 'Older Posts' );
                next_posts_link( 'Newer Posts', $heroPost->max_num_pages );
               the_posts_pagination();
               $wp_query = NULL;
               $wp_query = $temp_query;
               ?>
    
           
            </div>

          
           <div class = "blog_grid">
      

                  
                   
                
                </div>
     
            
            
            
            <div class = "blog_div">
              <h1 class = "read_more_title">Blog Navigation</h1>
              <form>
              
                <input type="text"></input>
                <button>Search</button>
                <button>By Category</button>
                <button>By Date</button>
                <button>List</button>
         
      
         
            </div>

        
            


           </div>
          </div>

          <?php get_footer(); ?>

          <!--<div class = "blog_div">
              <h3>tit</h3>
              <h4>Olivia Bennett</h4>
              <p> ex</p>
                 <a href="#">Read more</a>
            </div>
            <div class = "blog_div">
              <h3>My Day at the Spinster's House</h3>
              <h4>Olivia Bennett</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque ad quae saepe dolorum. 
                Sequi quidem doloremque, explicabo, necessitatibus eum dicta perferendis
                 totam ex dolor at eos quae aliquid iusto fugiat?</p>
                 <a href="#">Read more</a>
            </div>
            <div class = "blog_div">
              <h3>My Day at the Spinster's House</h3>
              <h4>Olivia Bennett</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque ad quae saepe dolorum. 
                Sequi quidem doloremque, explicabo, necessitatibus eum dicta perferendis
                 totam ex dolor at eos quae aliquid iusto fugiat?</p>
                 <a href="#">Read more</a>
            </div>-->
```

Comment: what's the error message for this in your PHP error log? If this is on your homepage you can avoid all of this by using the `pre_get_posts` filter to modify the main query rather than discarding it and creating a duplicate query

Comment: @TomJNowell good point! Looks like the error is: [Sat Sep 26 17:48:07.494624 2020] [php7:error] [pid 36768:tid 1892] [client ::1:59042] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$hero_args' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Cloudbank1\\wp-content\\themes\\Cloudbank1\\index.php on line 73, referer: http://localhost/Cloudbank1/blog/page/2/

But I'm not sure why it works for the page 1 to page 2, and not page 2 to page 3

Comment: I've taken a look and I've noticed you're using a custom query at the top to change the what posts WP fetches, then the code is bending over backwards to re-implement everything it got out of the box to fix things. Is there a reason you didn't use `pre_get_posts` to modify what WP fetches from the database instead of creating duplicate queries? I also noticed your query thinks there are 3 posts per page but your pagination thinks there is 1 post per page

Comment: I also notice some strange syntax, e.g. `<?php else:?>` is missing spaces around the `else` statement, and instead of `function()` and `$obj->method()` I'm seeing `function ()` and `$obj -> method()`, can you change these?

Comment: I have it set to 1 post per page just to try the pagination. On this page, there will ultimately be two custom loops to display two sets of posts with different parameters. Basically, featured posts and regular posts. To my understanding, pre_get_posts would only let me modify the main query, no?

Comment: @TomJNowell I think I diagnosed the problem. I made a stripped down version of the site with just one query and was encountering the same issue. I think the issue seems to be that if $my_custom_query, with max pages of '1', requires more pages than the default $wp_query allows for max_num_pages, it crashes.

By reducing "blogs shown per page" to 2 in the 'reading' setting, it actually doesn't whitescreen anymore, but this doesn't feel like a 'true' fix, and I'm still looking for info.